# Getting "error: closed" twice on "adb reverse"

Tags: android, adb, forwarding

I am trying to reverse-forward port through ADB, but it just returns cryptic error of `error: closed`. Normal forwarding works. Session snippet:

```
$ adb forward tcp:59778 tcp:59778
$ adb forward --list
015d2109ce0c1a0f tcp:59778 tcp:59778
$ adb forward --remove-all
$ adb forward --list
$ adb reverse --list
error: closed
error: closed
$ adb reverse tcp:59778 tcp:59778
error: closed
error: closed
```

I am connecting via USB to non-rooted Nexus 7 2012 Android 4.4.4 from Windows 7 Pro x64 on Boot Camp.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`adb reverse` was introduced in Android 5.0

Comment: So what's the solution when using Android 4.2?

Comment: Here's the solution: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-device-to-connect-to-the-dev-server-via-wi-fi

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger your link is not very clear on how to replace `adb reverse` on lower APIs. With setting the server manually on the device, I could develop react-native before but now I'm getting an error that among others suggests to `adb reverse` which fails, so I don't know how to go from there. Is setting the IP on the device sufficient to not need some other replacement?

Comment: Yes, but this is unfortunately not possible with an android version lower than 5. Unless someone builds the tool specifically but there are few chances this comes up since developers tend to move forward in versions (though this is not always for the best)

Comment: Marked useful: @alex-p means the installing device android version is not supported for debugging using `adb reverse`. Hope that clears it up for others. Took me a few minutes :) Note that this option is available on devices running android 5.0+ (API 21).

Comment: For Android 4.x and below, I have a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41640115/909944

Comment: adb: usage: reverse requires an argument | the error it's still not solved

Answer (score 35):

Since `adb reverse` is not supported in Android versions lower than 5.0, you need to use an alternative method, for example connecting via Wi-Fi instead. If you are using React Native, Facebook has added [official documentation to connect to the development server via Wi-Fi](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html). Quoting the instructions for MacOS, but they also have them for Linux and Windows:

> **Method 2: Connect via Wi-Fi**
>
> You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP address before proceeding.
>
> You can find the IP address in System Preferences → Network.
>
> Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
> Open your React Native app on your device.
> You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that.
> Open the in-app Developer menu.
> Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device.
> Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
> Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

Comment: Worked like a charm!. Thanks.

Comment: Best Answer!! Thanks

Comment: One more note: if you are like me who is developing on android 4 device (e.g. smart tv) which does not support shaking, you can still trigger in-app developer menu on the device by running: "adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU".

Comment: If you don't have a Wi-Fi network nearby, simply USB-tether your device and use the IP given to your computer-side interface!

Answer (score 13):

Follow these steps carefully.

Note: All commands need to run inside a project only.

1. Run this command first:

   ```
   npm react-native start
   ```
2. Open another window in the same project and run:

   ```
   curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
   ```
3. This will create `index.android.bundle` in the assets folder
4. Run:

   ```
   npm react-native run-android
   ```

Now you can get apk in the build folder which will work fine.

Comment: I think it should be 'react-native start' and 'react-native run-android' without 'npm'. npm is for package management...

Answer (score 5):

`adb reverse` requires Android 5.0+. For devices previous to that, you'll need to use a workaround like so.

If you have busybox installed on your Android device (most Genymotion images do), you can emulate `adb reverse` using this incantation:

`adb shell busybox nc -ll -p {guest port} -e busybox nc {host IP} {host port}`

In this case, "guest" is the Android OS running in the emulator and "host" is the computer running the emulator.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to get guest port, host IP, and host port?

I used adb devices to get the guest port. I then used ifconfig en0 to get the host ip, then I think the port is 8080 because I'm using react-native start --port=8080, however I get the error "nc: bind Address is already in use"

Comment: It will not work if 2 devices are not connected to the same network, just usb is not enough. What `busybox nc` does is tunneling streams. So why not connect to a single network via WiFi and modify bundle fetching host correspondingly to IP address of development machine?

Answer (score 2):

cause of adb reverse isnt working on android prior 5 you could propably use adb forward with a service listening on android and tunneling other connections through this inbound connection. I am doing this mostly with ssh, but you would need an ssh server on android. you than can connect using ssh -R incommingreverseportonandroid:hostyouwanttoforwardto:portyouwanttoforwardto sshuseronandroid@localhost -p portyouhaveusedforadbforwaqrdtoaccessandroidssshserver

but i dont know how to enable an ssh server on android and maybe there is a better way cause ssh uses encryption which isnt needed over usb and using up cpu.

i am using this way with my server to share a service when i am forced behind a nat...

hope someone will find a way to bring this teoretical way into practical possibility

Answer (score 0):

Just use 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 for your hostname. It will directly try to connect to the port on the host machine (same affect as reverse).