# Android failed to load JS bundle

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run AwesomeProject on my Nexus5 (android 5.1.1).

I'm able to build the project and install it on the device. But when I run it, I got a red screen saying

> Unable to download JS bundle. Did you forget to start the development server or connect your device?

In react native iOS, I can choose to load jsbundle offline. How can I do the same thing for Android? (Or at least, where can I configure the server address?)

### Update

#### To run with local server, run the following commands under your react-native project root directory

1. `react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &`
2. `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

please take a look at dsissitka's answer for more details.

#### To run without a server, bundle the jsfile into the apk by running:

1. create an assets folder under `android/app/src/main`
2. `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`

please take a look at kzzzf's answer for more details.

Comment: Stll haven't figured out the issue yet. But meanwhile, you can try it on your simulator. It's working perfectly fine on my genymotion.

Comment: when i try to type in the two commands to run with local server i get error in powershell saying: "The ampersand (&) character is not allowed". I assume I should be in the root of my app-dir when running the command?

Comment: Does this mean that debugging over USB on Android 4.1 is impossible since `adb reverse` isn't supported?

Comment: I'd like to mention that to be able to execute ```adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081``` you need ADB 1.0.32 version, ```reverse``` option is not in 1.0.31

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564252/react-native-0-57-cant-find-variable-require-with-metro-react-native-babel

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To bundle JS file into your apk while having your server running (`react-native start`) download bundle into assets directory of your app:

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

With the next release (0.12) we'll fix `react-native bundle` command to work with android projects as expected.

Comment: thank you! How do I tell reactInstanceManager to use the bundled asset? Or the magic just happens automatically?

Comment: It's defined using `setBundleAssetName` usually in the main activity (see template: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/generator-android/templates/package/MainActivity.java#L26)

Comment: Failed to create the file 
Warning: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle: No such file or 
Warning: directory

Comment: Do you have an answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170962/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundlechanges-in-index-android-js-cant

Comment: Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle: No such file or Warning: directory

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16167)

Comment: @Shivang: Create the directory assets in android/app/src/main. I had this error because it didn't exist yet.

Comment: This is the best and simple way when we distribute the app locally for testing purpose. (via fabric )  thanks

Comment: @kzzzf Failed writing body (0 != 6983)

Answer (score 91):

The following made it work for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
cd (App Dir)
react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

**Update**: See

- [Running On Device (Android)](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html)
- [Device warning suppressed?](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2690)

**Update 2**: @scgough We got this error because React Native (RN) was unable to fetch JavaScript from the dev server running on our workstations. You can see why this happens here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/42eb5464fd8a65ed84b799de5d4dc225349449be/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/devsupport/DevServerHelper.java#L116-L137

If your RN app detects that you're using Genymotion or the emulator it tries to fetch the JavaScript from GENYMOTION_LOCALHOST (10.0.3.2) or EMULATOR_LOCALHOST (10.0.2.2).
Otherwise it presumes that you're using a device and it tries to fetch the JavaScript from DEVICE_LOCALHOST (localhost).
The problem is that the dev server runs on your workstation's localhost, not the device's, so in order to get it to work you need to either:

- Forward traffic from (Device's localhost):8081/tcp to (Workstation's localhost):8081/tcp. That's what that adb command does.
- [Tell your RN app where it can find your dev server.](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-device-to-connect-to-the-dev-server-via-wi-fi)

Comment: running adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 on osx works as well

Comment: It works! thanks a lot. Do you know if there's a way to point jscodelocation to apk resource, just like iOS's main.jsbundle?

Comment: @dsissitka can I just ask so it's recorded here in the thread - what does that do exactly?

Comment: @Matthew Afraid not. Sorry!

Comment: What if we are running on Android 4.2 and getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525431/getting-error-closed-twice-on-adb-reverse?lq=1

Comment: Use the accepted answer for android version < 5.0 . For 5.0+ this works great.

Comment: why can't I run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in my app's root folder? the `adb` is not recognized here, i must run it in android sdk platform tool folder

Answer (score 39):

Ok, I think I've figured what the issue is here. It was to do with the version of `watchman` I was running.

In a new shell, run `brew update`
then: `brew unlink watchman`
then: `brew install watchman`

now, you can run `react-native start` from your project folder

I leave this shell open, create a new shell window and run: `react-native run-android` from my project folder. All is right with the world.

ps. I was originally on version 3.2 of watchman. This upgraded me to 3.7.

pps. I'm new to this so that might not be the swiftest route to the solution but it has worked for me.

*** MORE INFO FOR RUNNING/DEBUGGING ON A DEVICE ***

You might find that if you deploy your app to your Android device rather than an emulater you get a *red screen of death* with an error saying `Unable to load JS Bundle`. You need to set the debug server for your device to be your computer running react...either its name OR IP address.

1. Press the device `Menu` button
2. Select `Dev Settings`
3. Select `Debug server host for device` or `Change Bundle Location`
4. Type in your machine's IP and Reload JS plus the react port e.g. `192.168.1.10:8081`

More info: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

Comment: @jacobross85 Glad it helped! Give me an upvote if you feel like it ;-)

Comment: Had to run `brew uninstall watchman` before it would install the latest version for me.

Comment: I've added a bit more info for those debugging to an Android device rather than an emulator.

Comment: Was already running the latest version of watchman but this fixed it for me. Weeeeird

Comment: App crashes when I click on `Dev Settings`.

Comment: Thanks for this brother it's really helpful. That's why I'll give you the upvote.

Answer (score 17):

From your project directory, run

```
react-native start
```

It outputs the following:

```
$ react-native start
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │ 
 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │ 
 │  prefer.                                                                   │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │ 
 │                                                                            │ 
 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
Looking for JS files in
   /home/user/AwesomeProject 


React packager ready.

[11:30:10 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[11:30:10 PM] <START> Crawling File System
[11:30:16 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (5869ms)
[11:30:16 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[11:30:17 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (852ms)
[11:30:17 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[11:30:17 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (838ms)
[11:30:17 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[11:30:18 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[11:30:18 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (220ms)
[11:30:18 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (759ms)
[11:30:18 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (8319ms)
```

Comment: I'm also having the issue the OP reported. I run the project using `react-native run-android` from the project folder. It builds OK in terminal but as soon as the app opens on my device I get red screened saying `Unable to download JS bundle`

Comment: you need to run adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Comment: I ran adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 and I get error: closed error:closed

Comment: I have the same issue,  error: closed. Any help, please?

Comment: Make sure your ip address is correct in "Dev settings" if you're on Android. If you're working with a dynamic IP, this can change overnight.

Comment: What is 'Dev settings' and where is it found ? am new on this but facing the same problem?

Answer (score 13):

An easy solution that works for me with Ubuntu 14.04.

```
react-native run-android
```

The emulator (already launched) will return: Unable to download JS Bundle; start again the JS server:

```
react-native start
```

Hit Reload JS on the emulator.
It worked for me. Hope it will help

Comment: Actually works. Out of all the answers, this is the simplest solution. Can't believe this is not in the official doc.

Comment: The OP is about running on a device, not the emulator. These steps do not work on a device without additional setup. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

In the app on android I opened Menu (Command + M in Genymotion) -> Dev Settings -> Debug server host & port for device

set the value to: localhost:8081

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me

Answer (score 7):

After trying out a combination of the answers here, this is what is working for me.

I'm using Genymotion as my emulator.

1 Start up Genymotion emulator.

2 From a terminal

```
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android # it loads in genymotion and fails with bundle error
react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 & # from dsissitka
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 # from dsissitka
```

3 Reload from emulator.

It loads!

I can now begin developing.

Comment: getting Getting "error: closed" twice on "adb reverse"

Comment: FYI: I'm now doing the above with "Daniel Masarin" answer of setting the debug server host to my WiFi address with port 8081, it is working with RN v 0.17.0

Comment: thank you very much this works for me :) on above API 21+ only works this

Answer (score 4):

Delete the App from your phone! I tried several steps, but that did it eventually.

1. If you tried to run your app before but failed, **delete** it from your android device.
2. Run `$ react-native run-android`
3. Open the React Rage Shake Menu from within your app on your android device, go to `Dev Settings` and then to `Debug server host & port for device`. There enter your server IP (IP of your computer) and host `8081`, e.g. `192.168.50.35:8081`. On a mac you can find the IP of your computer at `System Preferences -> Network -> Advanced... -> TCP/IP -> IPv4 Address`.
4. Open the Rage Shake Menu again and click `Reload JS`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently adb reverse was introduced in Android 5.0 
[Getting "error: closed" twice on "adb reverse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525431/getting-error-closed-twice-on-adb-reverse)

I guess we have to go ahead with kzzzf's answer

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but this is referring to dsissitka's answer.
It works on Windows 10 as well.

To reiterate, the commands are:

```
cd (App Dir)
react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the simple steps to run your app on android(release):

**1. Go to your application root.**

**2. Run this command.**

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.android.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res

All your files are copied.

**3. Create signed APK.**

Open android studio.

**Build > Generate Signed APK >** [Fill required details, keystroke has to be generated before this step]

Your APK should be generated without any errors. Install on your device and this should work without any issues.

You can also connect your device and directly hit Run icon on android studio for testing.

---

**Generating Keystroke:**

1. Goto **C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin**
2. Run

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore d:\my_private_key.keystore -alias
>   my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

It will probably ask you to fill in some details. Do it and your have your keystroke file(**my_private_key.keystore**) which can be used to sign your apk.

Comment: after `react-native bundle` I got Error: Duplicate resources

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this on Linux after stopping down the `react-native run-android` process. Seems the node server is still running so the next time you run it, it won't run properly and your app can't connect.

The fix here is to kill the node process which is running in an Xterm which you can kill by `ctrl-c`ing that window (easier) or you can find it using `lsof -n -i4TCP:8081` then `kill -9 PID`.

Then run `react-native run-android` again.

Answer (score 1):

Check your wifi connection.

Another possibility could be you are either not connected to wifi, connected to the wrong network, or the ip address is wrong in your dev settings.  For some reason, my android disconnected from the wifi and I started to get this error, unknowingly.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. By default the Debug server is reached on the local network. Therefore if you have no wifi access you can't reach it.

Answer (score 1):

[Running on device](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html#configure-device-to-connect-to-the-dev-server-via-wi-fi)

I have found another answer.

- adb reverse: only work on Android 5.0+ (API 21).
- Another: Open the Developer menu by shaking the device, go to *Dev Settings*, Go to *Debug server host for device*, type in your *machine's IP address* and the *port of the local dev server*

Answer (score 1):

An update

Now on windows no need to run react-native start. The packager will run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to check that no one has mentioned so far:
**Check your local firewall, make sure it's turned OFF**.

See my response here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400708/1459275

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu and Android only, and I was unable to get it running. I found a really simple solution which is to update your package.json file, changing this lines:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
```

And then you run the server by typing

```
npm run start
```

This ensures the android device looks for the node server on your computer instead of locally on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880402/how-to-reload-react-native-app-in-mobile-device) was about reloading the application in a phyisical device.

When you're debugging the application in a physical device (ie via adb), you can reload the JS bundle by clicking on the top left "action" button of your device. This will open the option menu (Reload, Debug JS remotely...).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This error can easily resolved by following steps:

```
    //run the command at /android sdk / platforms-tool folder
        adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

    //now come to root folder of your app
    1. npm start
    2. create 'assets' folder inside rootApp/android/app/src/main/
    3. curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
    4. make sure anyone physical or virtual device attached is running.
    5. react-native run-android
```

Comment: can i run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in my app's root folder?

Comment: find the adb folder in your OS. its in Android SDK / platform tools /

Comment: but i see many places referring that this command can be run at app root folder, also the answer by dsissitka suggests that run it in root app folder, so im really confused.

Comment: may be this command is handle by react-native too. im not sure about this. but adb is supported by android sdk tools. you can find more details here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#method-1-using-adb-reverse-recommended

Comment: @MarsonMao Depending on your system setup, you may be able to run adb from your app directory. Read up on PATH variable, and global vs local packages for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instruction mentioned on the [official page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/running-on-device-android.html#content) to fix this issue. This issue occur on **real device** because the JS bundle is located on your development system and the app inside your real device is not aware of it's location.

Answer (score 0):

In new React Native (for sure 0.59) debug config is inside `android/app/src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
    <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start the two terminal on the same and 1st terminal run react-native start and second terminal react-native run-android this problem are solve in simply way. And best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was facing this issue with my react-native bare project, the IOS simulator works fine but android kept giving me this error. here is a possible solution which has worked for me.

step 1, check if the adb device is authorized by running in your terminal :  adb devices

if it is unauthorised run the following commands

step 2,  sudo adb kill-server
step 3,  sudo adb start-server

then check if the adb devices command shows
list of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

instead of unauthorized if it is device instead of unauthorized

step 4, run npx react-native run-android

this has worked in my instance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be weird but I got a solution.
I noticed that every once in a while my project folder went read-only and I couldn't save it from VS. So I read a suggestion to transfer NPM from local user PATH to system-wide PATH global variable, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

**### Here is my solution**

None of the above solutions can solve my problem but only follow the below steps working for me.
Add in `network-security-config.xml` file

```
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
    ...
```

Then update `AndroidManifest.xml` file with

```
<application
+   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Running **npm start** from react-native directory worked out for me.