# Android React Native Unable to download JS bundle TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of null

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have latest watchmen,nvm and npm but still i am getting Unable to load JS error. Here i am attaching my screen shot.

I gone through all stack over flow answers but i can't able to solve my issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the all the suggestions in this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle

Comment: Yes i tried all options but no use :(

Comment: i got the same error same like your screen shot    please help me i am on windows

Answer (score -1):

Finally i found whats went wrong.

1. Deleted existing project
2. Upadte Node JS and NVM
3. given path for NVM
4. `[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh`
5. `brew update`
6. `brew unlink watchman`
7. `brew install watchman`
8. restart mac
9. Then create new project
10. Successfully RUN.

Thanks for everyone.

Comment: i got the same error same like your screen shot    please help me i am on windows