# Is It possible to develop app with react native and make changes in android studio?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on React Native on Windows for android. i need to develop a app with react native. but i also need to make changes in that app in android studio. so is it possible to develop app like this?
Currently i follow this [tutorial](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/getting-started-with-react-native-android-and-couchbase-lite) in this tutorial a procedure to how to develop react native app in android studio but after build project it makes red screen shows **Unable to download js bundle** and also app crash in dev setting.
i was also follow [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969). and it runs successfully but it totally on react.js not open in android studio.
So please suggest me whether is it possible to develop app which able make changes in react.js and android studio?

Comment: For more info please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible as you can see in the tutorial.  What I think you did is just download the project and tried to compile/run it without even reading the whole tutorial.  If your error is something like this

```
Unable to download JS bundle. Did you forget to start the development server or connect your device?
```

You probably did not do the steps below

**JavaScript Land**

*In your project’s root folder, run:*

```
$ npm init
$ npm install --save react-native
$ curl -o .flowconfig https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/.flowconfig
```

*This creates a node module for your app and adds the react-native npm dependency. Now open the newly created package.json file and add this line inside of the scripts field:*

```
"start": "node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh"
```

Comment: what if you are trying to modify someone elses react-native package? do you just download the repo, open the android folder and build... or are there some standard steps you would need to do to make that work?