# React-native android failed to load js bundle:Changes in index.android.js can't see in apk

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I've setup react-native android project in my windows machine,for running i am using this command `react-native run-android` and i will get the installed apk in my phone.

Now i made some changes in `index.android.js` to see the changes  i'll press Reload JS from the rage shake menu.But i will get the following error.

> Unable to download js bundle.Did you forget to start the development
>   server or connect your device?

I've tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle) but its not worked for me,also I've setup `Debug server host for device`  with my machine Ipadress but it did't work.

**Note:**

Android version is 5+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution Do the following step by step

1.Go to project directory and Run your using the command `react-native run-android`.

2.open another command prompt in same directory and run the command `react-native start`

3.Open `Debug server host for device` option from rage shake menu and set the ipaddress with port 8081 eg:192.168.1.23:8081

Now you can see the changes of index.android.js in your app

**Note**

For getting ip address use `ipconfig` command ,if you enable live reloading option in your dev settings you can see instant changes without using Reloadjs.