# React-Native Cannot GET/ and JS Bundle

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This is the output I get when I run `react-native start`, and as you can see, it is giving a 404 error.

I have tried opening the page in chrome and it says `Cannot GET /`.

The app doesn't work on mobile either, even after connecting the device via wifi and entering the machine's IP address. It is stuck on the red screen saying `Unable to load JS Bundle.`

What's wrong?

```
   C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\SpeedRead>react-native start
     ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
     │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │
     │                                                                            │
     │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │
     │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │
     │  prefer.                                                                   │
     │                                                                            │
     │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │
     │                                                                            │
     └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    Looking for JS files in
       C:\Users\Abhishek\Desktop\SpeedRead

    [3:25:35 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
    [3:25:35 PM] <START> Crawling File System
    [3:25:35 PM] <START> Loading bundles layout
    [3:25:35 PM] <END>   Loading bundles layout (0ms)

    React packager ready.

    [3:25:44 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (9096ms)
    [3:25:44 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
    [3:25:45 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (554ms)
    [3:25:45 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
    [3:25:45 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (521ms)
    [3:25:45 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
    [3:25:46 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
    [3:25:46 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (95ms)
    [3:25:49 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (3482ms)
    [3:25:49 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (13858ms)
    ::1 - - [31/Jan/2016:09:56:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 13 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
    ::1 - - [31/Jan/2016:09:56:19 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 24 "http://localhost:8081/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36"
```

Questions I have seen:

[react native android failed to load JS bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle?rq=1)

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the packager is loading you need to navigate to `http://localhost:8081/js/index.android.bundle?platform=android`. If you still get a 404 there something is most likely wrong with your network configuration.

If you can pull it up on the web, run this with your phone plugged in via USB `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.