# Build and Install unsigned apk on device without the development server?

Tags: android, apk, react-native

As I am new in react-native so if there is anything wrong in steps let me know.

I have build a react native android app using the command as per documentation

> react-native android

while running on device the following command was used

> react-native run-android

which gives me the output of 2 apk files in my **projectfolder/android/app/build/outputs/apk**

[image]

now when I use to install this apk after the installation it ask for an development server to connect to bundle the JS. But my requirement is that the user doesn't have to struggle with the development server just he needs to install the apk and everything is done.

Have gone through some [stackoverflow Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle) but not helpful to build  unsigned apk which doesn't require development server.

Can you guys help me finding the way that how to build and unsigned apk in react native?

Comment: Run 'react-native start', it will server your js bundle in development mode. The purpose is so you can edit js files on the fly. Use release mode doesnt need any server as it will include the necessary bundle with it. See answer below

Answer (score 319):

You need to manually create the bundle for a debug build.

Bundle debug build:

```
#React-Native 0.59
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res

#React-Native 0.49.0+
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug

#React-Native 0-0.49.0
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

Then to build the APK's after bundling:

```
$ cd android
#Create debug build:
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
#Create release build:
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease #Generated `apk` will be located at `android/app/build/outputs/apk`
```

P.S. Another approach might be to modify gradle scripts.

Comment: In case someone is missing assets: this worked for me `--assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/`

Comment: This works but I had to do the following on windows:
1. Instead of "./gradlew assembleDebug", i had to run "gradlew assembleDebug" (without ./)
2. Open cmd as administrator to run the last command.

Comment: And if doing this gives me a big red screen when I start the app? (Note: I am running this directly after ejecting)

Comment: How to take build for latest version because we do not hve index.android.js ?

Comment: @VivekE Just use index.js

Comment: I had to use `--entry-file App.js` to get it to run. **Other note:** if you get a red error page in the app, try to put `AppRegistry.registerComponent('AppName', () => RootElement);
export default RootElement;` after (with appropriate import of AppRegistry) at the end of the file. Note that the export should follow the registration for it to work properly.

Comment: People with latest version, please change entry point to --entry-file index.js, thanks.

Comment: ***react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug***

    for the new reactnative version where the index.js is unified for ios and android

Comment: For some reason I had to build my "gradlew" file with: **cd android**, **gradle wrapper**. However, after that, when I run **gradlew assembleRelease** I run into the following issue: **Task 'assembleRelease' not found in root project 'android'.**

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: APK is generated but it does not let you install the apk on device. It says, 'APK not installed'.

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.default') i am getting this

Comment: and in release apk i am getting An error occurred:
4001504: Invalid .apk file: couldn't retrieve the signature, the app must be signed to be able to install it on a device

Comment: On RN v0.52.2 on linux, I needed to use a different bundle output and asset directory. Not sure why: `--bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res` <--- that worked for me

Comment: run this command after the above process: react-native run-android --variant=debug. And then install the apk generated at <your project directory>/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug on device. Reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618413/3301452]

Comment: after two steps when i run this command ./gradlew assembleDebug getting this error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I was getting [duplicate-file-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084810/react-native-android-duplicate-file-error-when-generating-apk), but this did the trick (because it is using the build dir as output)

Answer (score 135):

### React Version 0.62.1

In your root project directory

Make sure you have already directory **android/app/src/main/assets/**, if not create directory, after that create new file and save as `index.android.bundle` and put your file in like this **android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle**

After that run this

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Then you can get `apk` in **app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk**

Comment: @jeeva : how to connect application back to development server of react native ?

Comment: The point which create `index.android.bundle` is really important for not using development server in host.

Comment: @ Mayur Balha : You can connect back via usb or wifi (connected on same network). For WiFi connect back to server in your react app shake your mobile on emulator press Win+R then click dev settings Scroll down "Debug Server Host & Port"  enter your ip address and port( on windows open cmd enter "ipconfig" or Mac open terminal enter "ifconfig" ) like 192.168.1.1:8080 then press ok again shake or Press Win+R for emulator press reload now you can see app connect back to developement ( It will only working for Debug not for Release Apk ).

Comment: It's working fine on RN 0.62.1... Should be the correct answear in most recent version!

Comment: I had to run using npx:

npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

Answer (score 129):

Please follow those steps.

Bundle your js:

if you have index.android.js in project root then run

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

if you have index.js in project root then run

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Create debug apk:

```
cd android/
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Then You can find your apk here:

```
cd app/build/outputs/apk/
```

Comment: And if doing this gives me a big red screen when I start the app? (Note: I am running this directly after ejecting)

Comment: @SimonForsberg Did you find any solution? because i'm stuck at the same point.

Comment: @m4r00p: i did as you mentioned,but it gives me this error `Command bundle unrecognized. Make sure that you have run npm install and that you are inside a react-native project.` **note** i am building the app in jenkins

Comment: @SimonForsberg if you are using react ^0.5, change the entry point to index.js instead of App.js or index.android.js,

`react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug`

Comment: Not working, this commands building an apk but that apk is not running without packager server.

Comment: it is build apk but not able to install it

Comment: after two steps when i run this command ./gradlew assembleDebug getting this error '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This is not going to work, because it requires a dev server

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when generating the debug-APK, I could install it, but I need the dev server, and when I use the release APK, I could not install it on my phone, I don't know what is wrong with it

Comment: How to remove metrobundler dependancy for ios?

Answer (score 30):

With me, in the project directory run the following commands.

For react native old version (you will see index.android.js in root):

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleRelease && cd ../
```

For react native new version (you just see index.js in root):

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleRelease && cd ../
```

The apk file will be generated at:

- Gradle < 3.0: ***android/app/build/outputs/apk/***
- Gradle 3.0+: ***android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/***

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit and how does it solves the problem?

Comment: I was getting error opening in in index.android.bundle , and solved it by your suggestion. Thank you... :)

Comment: For me it is `$ mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug`

Comment: File not found: index.android.js in any of the project roots

Comment: Note that `--entry-file index.android.js` needs to be replaced with `--entry-file index.js` for newer projects that have `index.js` instead of `index.android.js` in the root of their project directory.

Comment: @daka you are wrong, index.android.js is the correct one

Answer (score 19):

After you follow the [first response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961021/2678755), you can run your app using

```
react-native run-android --variant=debug
```

And your app will run without need for the packager

Comment: the simplest answer was the most efficient all along, it worked flawless, spent days testing out different command lines and tons of js configurations, and everything was resumed in this

Answer (score 13):

As of react-native 0.57, none of the previously provided answers will work anymore, as the directories in which gradle expects to find the bundle and the assets have changed.

### Simple way without react-native bundle

The simplest way to build a debug build is without using the `react-native bundle` command at all, but by simply modifying your `app/build.gradle` file.

Inside the `project.ext.react` map in the `app/build.gradle` file, add the `bundleInDebug: true` entry.
If you want it to not be a `--dev` build (no warnings and minified bundle) then you should also add the `devDisabledInDebug: true` entry to the same map.

### With react-native bundle

If for some reason you need to or want to use the `react-native bundle` command to create the bundle and then the `./gradlew assembleDebug` to create the APK with the bundle and the assets you have to make sure to put the bundle and the assets in the correct paths, where gradle can find them.

As of react-native 0.57 those paths are
`android/app/build/generated/assets/react/debug/index.android.js` for the bundle

and `android/app/build/generated/res/react/debug` for the assets. So the full commands for manually bundling and building the APK with the bundle and assets are:

**`react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/generated/assets/react/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/res/react/debug`**

and then

**`./gradlew assembleDebug`**

### Bundle and assets path

Note that that paths where gradle looks for the bundle and the assets might be subject to change. To find out where those paths are, look at the `react.gradle` file in your `node_modules/react-native` directory. The lines starting with `def jsBundleDir =` and `def resourcesDir =` specify the directories where gradle looks for the bundle and the assets respectively.

Comment: The suggested paths do not match with the resulting `react-native bundle` command. And none of the variants ends up with bundle being part of the APK with React Native 0.63. See the description in [bug reported to React Native CLI docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1284).

Comment: But thanks for the suggestion with `bundleInDebug`. That's the right way to go. Using `react-native bundle` makes no sense when there are Gradle scripts taking care of everyghing.

Comment: The paths might have changed from react native 0.57 until now, so I don't know if the paths are still up to date.

Comment: Yes, [they've changed dramatically](https://gist.github.com/nikdo/0d294aeea72074e4dcab1660431a7285). Your answer is still the closest one to the optimal solution. I would just add a note that none of these paths is working anymore.

Answer (score 12):

## Generate debug APK without dev-server

If you really want to **generate a debug APK** (for testing purpose) that can run **without the development server**, Congrats! here I am to help you. :)
Everyone is saying that we need to run two commands `react-native bundle ...` and then `gradlew assembleDebug` but the generated APK still doesnot work without development server. After many research & try I figured out that we need to change in the gradle file (as in step-2). Just follow these steps:

1. In your react native project go to `/android/app/src/main` create a folder `assets`
2. edit `android > app > build.gradle`

```js
project.ext.react = [
    ...
    bundleInDebug: true, // add this line
]
```

3. run this command at the root directory of your react native project

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

4. Now, go into the android folder: `cd android`
5. And, run this command: `gradlew assembleDebug`
   (if build failed, try building assembleDebug from android studio)

This will create `app-debug.apk` file in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug` directory, which you can install & run without dev-server.

Comment: For me after copying assets, I faced duplicate resources issue.

Comment: I upvoted this answer as step 2 Adding bundleInDebug: true)  is necessary to make it work without a server. Tested with react-native 0.66.  You do end up with duplicate resources in android/app/build/generated/res/react/debug/  and android/app/src/main/res  The solution is to delete the duplicates in the latter directory

Answer (score 9):

There are two extensions you can use for this. This is added to react-native for setting these:

1. `disableDevInDebug: true`: Disables dev server in debug buildType
2. `bundleInDebug: true`: Adds jsbundle to debug buildType.

So, your final `project.ext.react` in `android/app/build.gradle` should look like below

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    devDisabledInDev: true, // Disable dev server in dev release
    bundleInDebug: true, // add bundle to dev apk
]
```

Comment: in your code should be bundleInDebug instead bundleInDev

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. both `devDisabledInDev` and `bundleInDebug` should be set to true!

Answer (score 7):

For Windows user if all steps followed properly from this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

**You need to only run:** `gradlew assembleRelease`

*And your file will be:*

- app-release.apk
- app-release-unaligned.apk

**Location:** `E:\YourProjectName\android\app\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: You can install/share app-release.apk to any device

Comment: Usually, the debug build has a different configuration than the release build (e.g. it uses a staging API). This doesn't help if you want a standalone APK that uses a different build configuration from the release

Comment: This APK is just for development/Testing purpose.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case someone else is recently getting into this same issue, I'm using React Native 0.59.8 (tested with RN 0.60 as well)  and I can confirm some of the other answers, here are the steps:

1. Uninstall the latest compiled version of your app installed you have on your device
2. Run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. run `cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug`
4. Get your app-debug.apk in folder android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug

good luck!

Comment: Doesn't work!!!, it generate the debug APK, but the app still need the dev server

Comment: This can't work in react-native 0.59.8, as gradle expects the bundle to be in `android/app/build/generated/assets/react/debug/index.android.js` and the assets to be in `android/app/build/generated/res/react/debug` as of react-native 0.57.

Comment: Works fine for react native 0.60 >

Answer (score 6):

It can be possible to generate an unsigned apk version for testing purpose so you can run on your mobile.

Initially i got the red screen errors as most mentioned here. but i followed the same which was mentioned here and it worked for me.

On your console from working directory, run these four commands

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug

cd android

gradlew assembleDebug

gradlew assembleRelease
```

And then APK file will produce on : android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

Answer (score 5):

quite late for the party but none of the solutions `at least on page 1` does not work for me. Thus I looked a bit deeper into the grade tasks registered by react;

just add `bundleInDebug : true` as shown in @Er Suman G's answer

run `./gradlew assembleDebug` or `gradle.bat assembleDebug` based on your environment in your android folder.

This will generate the debuggable non server required app in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug`

Answer (score 4):

I'm on react native 0.55.4, basically i had to bundle manually:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle- 
output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets- 
dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

Then connect your device via usb, enable usb debugging. Verify the connected device with `adb devices`.

Lastly run `react-native run-android` which will install the debug apk on your phone and you can run it fine with the dev server

Note:

- From 0.49.0, the entrypoint is a single `index.js`
- `gradlew assembleRelease` only generates the release-unsigned apks which cannot be installed

Answer (score 2):

Generate debug APK without dev-server

If you want to generate a debug APK (for testing purposes) that can run without the development server.

1. In your react native project go to `/android/app/src/main` create a folder `assets`
2. edit `android > app > build.gradle`

```js
universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
```

3. run this command at the root directory of your react native project

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

4. Now, go into the android folder: `cd android`
5. And, run this command: `./gradlew assembleDebug`
   (if build failed, try building assembleDebug from android studio)

Just do this things.

and if you want to install app in device just run cmd

```
adb install 'path/add-debug.apk'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `devDisabledInDebug: true` to `project.ext.react` in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to profile my app from Android Studio which builds a debug build and I hit the issue of no packaged bundle. I could build a release build with `<profileable android:shell="true"/>` and attach the profiler after starting, but I needed specifically to profile my app's startup so there wasn't enough time to attach and I couldn't figure out how to launch a release build with the profiler. So I needed a way to build the debug build with the bundle. I'm running Expo 50 and React Native 0.73.4 and instead of the following in `build.gradle`:

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    devDisabledInDev: true, // Disable dev server in dev release
    bundleInDebug: true, // add bundle to dev apk
]
```

I had to use [`debuggableVariants`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/react-native-gradle-plugin#debuggablevariants):

```
react {
    debuggableVariants = []
}
```

If editing the `build.gradle` file in Android Studio, after adding the above line and saving, click `Sync Now` in the top right. Then I could connect my phone and Run } `Profile 'app' with complete data`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution changing buildTypes like this:

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well, apparently i forgot to import the variable