# React-native debug apk

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to get debug version of react-native app. For release version of apk, i am using >cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease. Generated apk will be stored at app/build/outputs/apk.

Is there any command like this to generate debug version of apk? Please let me know the path where it stores.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Use

> cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug

to generate debug apk.

Apk will be generated in directory

> app/build/outputs/apk

apk name 'app-debug.apk'

Comment: I don't why but the apk generated in this way doesn't work, I just see a completely white screen

Comment: @Apperside You might need to bundle your app. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/35283959/1310566

Comment: @Apperside if you build by debug, it will need a server for the app to get the js bundle on the fly.

Answer (score -3):

the debug apk requires development server to be running.
so please use "react-native start" to start the server and run your app in the same network as of your pc.
now change the development server and port setting in your mobile to the Ip address of your pc and 8081 port.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Not needed if the app has been bundled, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35283959/1310566