# React Native Xiomi-Android 4.4 - MainActivity Permission Denied. Works Fine in Genymotion-4.4

Tags: android, react-native

The Problem:  Please see this link [DropBox Image Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ot58m8duzriwqoq/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-25%20at%2010.47.02%20PM.png?dl=0)
I have gone through almost all answers. First of all I want to tell what I have already tried -

1. Wifi issue - I think, this is not my problem but for considering issue My phone and My Mac both are in same Wi-Fi.
2. I have also gone through this [Issue On Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2790)  and All links commented by people in this issue. Because That is the exact problem I have.
3. Finally I tried , The code which is working in my genymotion android 4.4, I took appdebug.apk, put into my mobile xaiomi with android-4.4 and installed it manually . And uhhh... same thing.  just white screen nothing else.
4. So Last thing i thought there may be some permission issues, So I checked out in my phone that "pop-up are blocked". So I un-blocked it manually and whoaaaa.. finally I got this [Image Link](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1212932/9962204/1e947810-5e57-11e5-817b-022a1dad612c.jpg)

Now Please if someone have any solution which is not in Internet, Please provide. If issue will be solved, I will order a Pizza for you :).

Comment: Have you tried with releaseBuild apk in phone?

Comment: I have no Idea about releaseBuild apk. What is location of this apk ?@Jickson

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37455194/2125612. This will generate debug apk which you can run in any device without the js server.

Comment: @Jickson its not working. I think its my Xiaomi problem. If you have any solution for this issue. Please add here. TIA