# React Native Android Duplicate file error when generating apk

Tags: android, react-native, apk

When I am trying to generate android apk by using `./gradlew installRelease`, I get this error in console:

```
~/React-Native/mockingbird/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-mdpi-v4/src_resources_img_loading.gif: error: Duplicate file.
~/React-Native/mockingbird/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/drawable-mdpi/src_resources_img_loading.gif: Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.
```

I tried `Build->Clean Project` via Android Studio and ran `./gradlew installRelease` again; it didn't work either.

Also, I tried deleting the `build` folder, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: That's a really weird thing i've faced too. One of the quick solutions is to remove drawable resources completely (or just move somewhere outside the project directory) and rebuild the project.

Comment: @AleksandrMedvedev Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work here 

Comment: please check my answer to a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066718/427622

Comment: Simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245362/6898523

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Give some tips for you, hope it's work.

Update with "react": "16.7.0", "react-native": "0.57.8"

Custom **node_modules/react-native/react.gradle** to solve the *Duplicate file error* perfectly. Add following code into **currentBundleTask**'s creation block (**after doFirst block**)

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

---

You can create script to do it automatically.

1. Create [`android-react-gradle-fix`](https://github.com/beesightsoft/bss-rct-build-release/blob/master/Script/src/android-react-gradle-fix) file
2. Create script [`android-release-gradle-fix.js`](https://github.com/beesightsoft/bss-rct-build-release/blob/master/Script/src/android-release-gradle-fix.js) file
3. Update `package.json` file:

   "scripts": {
       **"postinstall": "node ./android-release-gradle-fix.js"**
   },

That's it! Run `npm install` to get awesome.

**Note:** If you run `npm install` on ci like jenkins, you may get error: `postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) node` => just use `npm install --unsafe-perm` instead

Comment: This solution worked for me, but my question is how does this error happen in the first place since it only happens on my side branch that I share with another developer?

Comment: Thank you so much..you saved my ass. 
Although i have a question, do i need to insert this code everytime after running npm install,
Is it a good idea to modify gradle from node_modules? i seriously doubt it

Comment: This is in react-native now (I'm on version 0.56.0) but I still have this error. I'm starting to go crazy, this is blocking me for way too long now.

Comment: @ThaJay on 0.56.0 this script does not work, you need to there are lower number of spaces when doing replace regexp and script does not change anythink

Comment: @bobu I noticed something like that in the code. Scripts that depend on such things are always bad. I eventually just deleted the whole contents of the folder and just put back what I need which is `drawable`, `mipmap`, `raw`, `values`. Notice there is no postfix on any of them.

Comment: There's a [slight change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52750886/1701465) that needs to be made to this function in order to make the workaround compatible with the latest versions of RN/Gradle.

Comment: This solution does not work if you are using react native >=0.57, @Cawfree 's solution does

Comment: I modified the regex like so `/\s\/\/ Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result/g)` to make it a bit more robust.

Comment: this didn't work for me, removing files in `drawable` did.

Comment: @Apperside, what is Cawfree's solution, can you link me to it please.

Comment: This solution is too extreme. You can't modify `node_modules` folder files. If you feel like you have to, it means you're doing something wrong. Next answer in this thread is more like it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589616/925307

Comment: Yey, it worked! Thank you so much. this was the most frustrating issue

Comment: I am using react-native 0.61.1. And getting the same error as Duplicate resource. Anyone of you have any idea how to fix it.?

Answer (score 40):

At the time of writing, the more recent versions of React Native (>0.57.0) have increased the Gradle wrapper level to 4.4 and the Gradle plugin to 3.1.4, as indicated by the [changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). This has the effect of making the Gradle build process store the results of AAPT, which are now **required**, within a different directory than previously.

In terms of [Nhan Cao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5855770/nhan-cao)'s [awesome workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47094457/1701465), we need to make a slight modification to prevent duplicate resource collisions, since it looks to be pointed at the old directory and not the app's `generated` directory. By changing the target directory where these duplicate files are merged together after the resources have been generated, we can still dedup the resources.

The existing `react.gradle` refers to the path below:

```
$buildDir === <project-working-directory>/android/app/build
```

The duplicate file paths can appear between:

```
file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}")
file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}")
```

As a workaround, we can update Nhan's solution as follows (be sure to include this within the `currentBundleTask` after the declaration of `doFirst` in `react.gradle`:

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

If your app depends on `/raw` assets too, the method outlined below should help you:

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
     }
     moveFunc.curry("drawable-ldpi").call()
     moveFunc.curry("drawable-mdpi").call()
     moveFunc.curry("drawable-hdpi").call()
     moveFunc.curry("drawable-xhdpi").call()
     moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxhdpi").call()
     moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxxhdpi").call()
     moveFunc.curry("raw").call()
}
```

If your app also uses a custom "build types" other than `release`, such as `preRelease` or `stagingRelease`(Android Gradle Plugin allows you to define them in `build.gradle`), you should change `originalDir` variable like below:

```
# from
File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
# to 
File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetName}/drawable-${resSuffix}");
```

Comment: For anyone who build an apk with productFlavors the originalDir in this answer should update accordingly; for example mine would be "$buildDir/generated/res/react/develop/release/drawable-${resSuffix}"

Comment: wow, thank you for saving my day, that's really helpful and appreciative

Answer (score 37):

Remove the files you might have on:

```
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/
```

Run Build again, This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I cleaned out the whole `res/` folder and backed it up. Then I only added `mipmap/ic_launcher.png` and `values/` with `strings.xml` and `styles.xml`.
Now it finally works after the most frustrating day and a half this year.

Comment: its works perfect for me... i am resolving from last one day.. thnx a lot

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. I normally only build from the command line, and when opening the project in Android Studio I didn't notice it created these directories and thus duplicate resources.

Comment: "Android resource linking failed" :/

Comment: For me works - remove folder `android/app/src/main/res/raw`

Answer (score 20):

#### Do not run `react-native bundle` prior to `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

For myself, I was running `react-native bundle` prior to running `./gradlew assembleRelease`.

I was getting a similar duplicate error message with one of my assets.

Looking at the `./gradlew assembleRelease` output, I could tell that it builds the JS bundle by itself (thanks to `apply from: "../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` in your `build.gradle` file) so it was not necessary to manually run `react-native bundle` before hand.

If I simply did not run `react-native bundle` before running `./gradlew assembleRelease` everything worked great.

I tested the Release APK and the JS bundle loads fine, including all images.

My only concern is whether the source maps `--sourcemap-output` (for Bugsnag) will be created. If not, I'm sure there's a way to have `./gradlew assembleRelease` generate those as well. I just have not tested it yet.

Comment: Didn't work for me. The accepted answer solved it for me, but had to also put android.enableAapt2=false into the gradle.properties file.

Comment: Coming back to my own answer here. This used to fix it but even after remove the bundle prior to `assembleRelease`, it's not longer working on React Native 0.57.8.

Comment: Hmm, coming back here and it's still the correct answer for me. The only duplicate resource errors I was getting were related to `react-navigation`. We were on an old version, `2.3.1`, and after upgrading to `2.18.3` the error went away. But, bundling the react-native JS before running `./gradlew assembleRelease` still caused the error.

Comment: coming back now, you never need to manually bundle the js, assembleRelease will do it for you, so you are right. (also, you can delete the index.android.bundle, no need for that, only if building via Android Studio)

Answer (score 6):

In order to get my build working for React Native 0.57.5, I used [Mapsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701465/mapsy)'s answer with a minor enhancement. I needed to be able to build for multiple flavors and generally I try to avoid hardcoding things. When looking through my `react.gradle` file, I found it had the following variable defined:

```
def resourcesDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetPath}")
```

So instead of hardcoding the build type/flavor in the path like this:

```
File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
```

I instead used the `resourcesDir` variable to set the `originalDir` path like this:

```
File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}");
```

As a result, my `doLast` looks like this:

```
doLast {
            def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
                File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}");
                if (originalDir.exists()) {
                    File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
                    ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
                }
            }
            moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
            moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
            moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
            moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
            moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
            moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it work to remove the folder: `android/build` and run `./gradlew assembleRelease` again.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was simply adding this extra command in `package.json`, and use that for building:

```
    "android-build-release": "cd ./android && rm -rf app/src/main/res/drawable* && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease",
```

Comment: worked like a charm, on `0.56.0` and up, the selected solution (updating `react.gradle`) is not working. This one really should be selected as the right one

Answer (score 2):

1.Delete drawable-xxx folders
2.Delete raw
inside src -> main -> res folder then

3.run this command in terminal:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res_temp
```

4.then generate signed apk using keystore, alias and passwords using terminal or android studio

Answer (score 0):

A way to remove the error would be to:

- put your images in the android/app/src/main/res/drawable folder (create a “drawable” folder if one doesn’t exist)
- delete all the drawable folders that have suffixes (i.e. drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, etc)
- don’t bundle assets (i.e. don’t run: react-native bundle …)
- run Gradle’s assembleRelease

However, this is not an ideal solution because each image will only have one resolution for all device sizes. For images that are too big for a device it leaves downscaling to the device and leads to download size and speed issues, and for images too small for a device it leads to diminished image quality.

One convenient solution I’ve found is to use an Android Studio plugin called Android Drawable Importer. To use it after it is installed:

- open your project in Android studio and navigate to: android/app/src/main/res/drawable
- right click on the folder and choose: New > Batch Drawable Import
- select and configure image assets to import

The plugin will handle the generation of the drawable folders and correct image sizes. Once you’ve imported your image, you should be able to run Gradle’s assembleRelease without the duplicate resources error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is running into this and the doLast solution isn't working it's because you do not have to run react-native bundle anymore before you run bundleRelease. This took hours of head banging because of how many posts out there I found saying doLast solves it.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Esben von Buchwald 's answer, i added to the script to delete raw folder also.

```
"android-build-release": "cd ./android && rm -rf app/src/main/res/drawable* && rm -rf app/src/main/res/raw && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease",
```

Hope it works for you