# React-Native assembleRelease fails for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle

When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease` build is failed with this error:

> ```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets. 
> > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'node'
> ```

I searched on the internet and found some topics about it, but I couldn't solve my problem.

React-Native version: 0.54.0

EDIT:
Now I'm running `./gradlew assembleRelease --info` from the terminal instead of Android Studio and I get different error.
 Here is the result:

```
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:processReleaseResources' into context took 0.007 secs.
file or directory '**/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-analytics/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-interactable/lib/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '**/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/appcenter-analytics/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-interactable/lib/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/libs', not found
Executing task ':app:processReleaseResources' (up-to-date check took 0.035 secs) due to:
  Task has failed previously.
All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
Unable do incremental execution: full task run
file or directory '**/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-analytics/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-interactable/lib/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '**/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-crashes/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter-analytics/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/appcenter/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-interactable/lib/android/libs', not found
file or directory '**/node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/libs', not found
Aapt2QueuedResourceProcessor is using **/Android/sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
*
*
*
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

It seems gradle is looking for libs folder in all modules, but there are no libs folders in the node modules. It's true, but I don't know why gradle is looking for libs folder.

Comment: Have you tried adding the path where your node binary is located to the PATH environment variable?

Comment: @Ch4t4r Yes I have

Answer (score 81):

First:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

finally build:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Comment: WHen I run this in my cli it is successfully building but the APK is unsigned and when I try and sign the APK via Android studio I am getting the error above

Comment: The above almost worked for me, but when I run the build, I get: `Task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' not found in root project`

Comment: just ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets saved me. Thx

Comment: Getting  Task :react-native-firebase-analytics:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase-analytics:verifyReleaseResources'.

Comment: If you run Windows 10, use cmd with administrator rights (no git bash), make sure that you're using the actual version of @react-native-community/cli, that directory android/app/src/main/assets exists and use yarn react-native bundle instead of react-native bundle

Comment: This helps a lot

Comment: if someone gets the error `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'` , you must create the `assets` folder in main directory . [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58767106/7500651)

Comment: it work in first phase , in the seccond time after i do some development and update some file , it also work but updated feature not shown 
it stuck in first phase

Answer (score 25):

Looks like you haven't made a js bundle so please make a bundle first by using command :-

```
 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

then in your project directory

```
 cd android
```

Clean your gradle

```
 ./gradlew clean
```

and make a build finally

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Try this.
Hope it will helps you.

Comment: this worked for build debug but  './gradlew assembleRelease' give me errors  still

Comment: it work in first phase , in the seccond time after i do some development and update some file , it also work but updated feature not shown

Comment: ` ./gradlew clean` alone made it for me!

Answer (score 22):

Just using `./gradlew --stop` and then `./gradlew assembleRelease` worked for me.

Answer (score 22):

For me the creating the bundle failed, but I noticed this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52068632/10564312) by [Sahin Elidemir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6470308):

> just ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets saved me.

It almost worked for me. What worked at the end was (notice the `app:`, which for me it fails without, and a `clean` for good measure):

```
./gradlew clean app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, the solution was :

`cd` to **yourApp/android** folder

run this

`./gradlew --stop`

and then

`./gradlew assembleRelease`

This gonna build your app.

After build is done, go to see your application(apk).

**android\app\build\outputs\apk\release**

Answer (score 9):

> This is working for me, Please follow the below steps:-

**1) Stop Running Gradle**

```
 $ cd RectNatoveProjectName & cd android  (Open your project and go to android folder)  
 $ ./gradlew --stop (Run this command to stop old running Gradle service )
```

**2) Update the android app build gradle**

```
project.ext.react = [
        nodeExecutableAndArgs : ["/usr/local/bin/node"]
];
```

**3) Get Node details**

```
$ which node
```

*> (Result will be like "/usr/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node")*

**4) Link node (very imp step copy the above result in step 3)**

```
- ln -s /usr/username/.nvm/versions/node/v10.7.0/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
```

**5) If Step - 4 return file exist**
   - then to go the folder /usr/local/bin/ and delete the "node" file and perform the step -4 again.

**6) If Step - 4 run successfully then this node issue will be resolved.**

Answer (score 4):

I now this is late. may be this will help somebody.

For me it i had to upgrade to latest `react-native-sentry`.

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-sentry/sentry.gradle"
```

was causing problem

Comment: They changed to a new npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sentry/react-native which I completely missed!

Answer (score 3):

The steps above really helped.

Here's the scripts that work for us with `react-native 0.55.3`.

Run the `android-build` command locally or CI to generate an APK.

**/packages.json** (react-native):

```
"android-bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
"android-release-fix": "node ./android-release-gradle-fix.js",
"android-build": "yarn killbin && yarn android-clean && yarn android-release-fix && yarn android-bundle && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets --info",
"android-clean": "cd android && ./gradlew clean",
"killbin": "rm -rf ./node_modules/.bin",
```

**android-release-gradle-fix.js**:

```
const fs = require('fs')

// Fix issues with Android resources like duplicate files
// CI: run install with --unsafe-perm option
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084810/react-native-android-duplicate-file-error-when-generating-apk
try {
        var curDir = __dirname
        var rootDir = process.cwd()

        var file = `${rootDir}/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle`
        var dataFix = fs.readFileSync(`${curDir}/android-react-gradle-fix`, 'utf8')
        var data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')

        var doLast = "doLast \{"
        if (data.indexOf(doLast) !== -1) {
            throw "Already fixed."
        }

        var result = data.replace(/                \/\/ Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result/g, dataFix);
        fs.writeFileSync(file, result, 'utf8')
        console.log('Done')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
```

**android-react-gradle-fix**

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}")
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}-v4")
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir)
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}

// Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result
```

**/android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
...
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**/android/app/build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':amazon-cognito-identity-js')
    implementation project(':appcenter-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation(project(':react-native-google-signin')) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$googlePlayServicesVersion" // Google signin
    implementation project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2"
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibVersion"
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    // implementation "com.android.support:$supportLibVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this and it works:

- Removed node modules (you can do it by running this command `rm -rf node_modules`)
- Run `npm install` or `yarn install`
- Then run `./gradlew clean` && `./gradlew app:assembleRelease` or `./gradlew app:assembleDebug`

Comment: @punjabi4life didn't saw that 

Answer (score 3):

if you are using macOS and using react native try this:

1. `brew install react-native-cli`
2. `./gradlew --stop`
3. `./gradlew clean`
4. `./gradlew aR`or `./gradlew assembleRelease`

Comment: I'm very grateful for this solution, but it's the second time that I had to use it. Is there no permanent fix for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For me:

- OS: `Windows`.
- I just copied the .keystore file to android\app.
- `cd android && gradlew --stop` then `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Answer (score 2):

This error also occurs when you have stacked your project inside many folders

**Try** copying your project folder into one of your hard drives without putting that project into any folder.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong image size (i.e image@5x.png) which caused me this problem. When I deleted that image@5x.png file...it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

As of RN 0.58, for CI builds the commands is as follows:

First create directories:

`mkdir -p app/build/generated/assets/react/production/release/ && mkdir -p app/build/generated/res/react/production/release`

Next:

`node ../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output app/build/generated/assets/react/production/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest app/build/generated/res/react/production/release --max-workers 1 --reset-cache`

Also you may also want to add for your production builds according to [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md);

`--minify true`

Taken from [RN's source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.58-stable/react.gradle)

NOTE: We added `--max-workers 1` not to deplete CI resources since they are limited to lower numbers (mem&cpu).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, after a few hours, I saw this on GitHub: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/578#issuecomment-503428032.
I had renamed the project on Sentry. If you renamed the project on, update the `android/sentry.properties` and `ios/sentry.properties` file.

```
defaults.url=https://sentry.io/
defaults.org=yourorg
defaults.project=newprojectname
auth.token=
```

And that's it, i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking all your JS (React native). I faced this issue coz have a coding error in the JS file (React native).

Answer (score 1):

if you are running these commands in VS code,
Just open the project in cmd (administrator mode) in android folder run
**$ gradlew clean**
**$ gradlew assembleRelease**

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

1- `android\app\build.gradle`

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false, 
]
```

2-

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

3- `gradlew bundleRelease`

Answer (score 1):

In my case

**npx** was not able to go into the correct directory due to a space in the parent directory name

example :-

```
D:\dk\native\aiims raipur\aiimsraipur
```

Removed space from directory -> **aiims raipur** to **aiims_raipur**

Build works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First thing before trying other stuffs you should do the below:

cd yourProject/android and run

./gradlew --stop

and

./gradlew clean

next try again. Sometimes, when you update the assets you might have that gradle issue within terminal

Answer (score 0):

Check your project to make sure that you didn't name any of your folders with spaces in between.
For me, there was a space in the name of my project's parent folder.
When I remove the space (from `Source Codes` to `codes`) my build was successful.

Answer (score 0):

try `android/app/build.gradle`

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
```

in new rn versions it is set to true

then

```
gradlew clean
gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

The solution is so simple,

your project ancestors folder names should not contain spaces, like:
`D:\Documents\React Native\MyRNProjectTest`
in this "React Native" folder has space in it, removing the space from folder name could solve the problem, like this "ReactNative".

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue on Mac OS, was related to metro-bundler not having access to the folder in which my project was kept. I restarted my system and re-run the command. The bundler asked for permission to access the folder and after that I was able to generate the build.

Hope it helps. Thanks

P.S : All the fixes mentioned did not work for me.