# Task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' not found in root project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am unable to get a successful build with the React Native project in Jenkins. I get this error:

> 14:41:59 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 14:41:59  14:41:59 *
>   What went wrong: 14:41:59 Execution failed for task
>   ':app:bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets'. 14:41:59 > Process 'command
>   'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 14:41:59

I did find an answer here:

[React-Native assembleRelease fails for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513047/react-native-assemblerelease-fails-for-task-appbundlereleasejsandassets#answers-header)

The problem is when its time to build, the second step:

`./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' not found in root project 'engage-application.mobile'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Running `gradlew tasks` does not provide any insights to me:

```
✗ gradle tasks

> Task :tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
Tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Build Setup tasks
-----------------
init - Initializes a new Gradle build.
wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

Help tasks
----------
buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'engage-application.mobile'.
components - Displays the components produced by root project 'engage-application.mobile'. [incubating]
dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'engage-application.mobile'.
dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'engage-application.mobile'.
dependentComponents - Displays the dependent components of components in root project 'engage-application.mobile'. [incubating]
help - Displays a help message.
model - Displays the configuration model of root project 'engage-application.mobile'. [incubating]
projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'engage-application.mobile'.
properties - Displays the properties of root project 'engage-application.mobile'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'engage-application.mobile'.

To see all tasks and more detail, run gradle tasks --all

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Also, notice I had to run `gradle tasks`.

The few related articles on SO are either 3 to 5 years old and speaks to versions of

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
```

inside of `build.gradle` that are not appropriate for my version of RN:

```
System:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
  CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Memory: 609.73 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node: 11.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.10.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
  Android SDK:
    API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28
    Build Tools: 23.0.1, 26.0.2, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
    System Images: android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.4 AI-183.5429.30.34.5452501
  Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3
  react-native: 0.57.8 => 0.57.8
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

I recently upgraded to version 0.57.8 and followed this guide:
https://reactnative.thenativebits.com/courses/upgrading-react-native/upgrade-to-react-native-0.57/

It was explained to me that I needed to run:

`✗ ./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets`

and I did and I continue to get the error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets' not found in root project 'engage-application.mobile'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

If I then try to follow the step by Kartik Shah:
[React-Native assembleRelease fails for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513047/react-native-assemblerelease-fails-for-task-appbundlereleasejsandassets#answers-header)

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-sentry:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
208 actionable tasks: 195 executed, 13 up-to-date
```

I ran into this issue three days ago and I thought with the upgrade it would be resolved:

https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/issues/610

So I upgraded React Native Sentry and the errors I get now are as follows:

```
The TaskInternal.executer property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. There are better ways to re-use task logic, see https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:reusing_task_logic.
        at sentry_c79fxbhuascug468f001tukcq$_run_closure1$_closure6.doCall(/Users/danale/Projects/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/react-native-sentry/sentry.gradle:19)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
/Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/478ea8d2caa80bc12b39e3960167e1f6/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

/Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/478ea8d2caa80bc12b39e3960167e1f6/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

/Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/478ea8d2caa80bc12b39e3960167e1f6/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking references.
```

It seems like the offending code is around here:

```
def bundleTasks = tasks.findAll { task -> task.name.startsWith("bundle") && task.name.endsWith("JsAndAssets") && !task.name.contains("Debug")}
    bundleTasks.each { bundleTask ->
        def shouldCleanUp
        def sourcemapOutput
        def bundleOutput
        def props = bundleTask.getProperties()
        def reactRoot = props.get("workingDir")
```

Does anyone have any workaround or experience with this for React Native Sentry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I see is that your original error is for task `bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets` as opposed to the `bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` task that failed in the other post that you linked. So possibly try running this instead:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets
```

Basically as-is you were telling it to exclude a task that might not be part of your project. You have to specify the correct one.

Comment: Sophon,  even when I run `bundleDevReleaseJsAndAssets` I still get that error. I will add it above.

Answer (score 2):

Below works fixed my issue.

**android/app/build.gradle**

make sure below mentioned added or Not.

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"  
 
apply from:"../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
```

Make sure, your enabled:

```
android{ defaultConfig{
 
    multiDexEnabled true } }
 
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Delete **.gradle** folder from the android folder

Run:

```
 react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0):

for the issue was i an import was changed miskatenly. What is have imported was like this.

```
import interstialsAdCustomHook from '../Hooks/InterstialsAdCustomHook';
```

the file as defined like this

```
interstialsAdCustomHook.js
```

the differnce was capital and small letters.