# Error: The resource `Path-to-project-root-directory\index.ts` was not found

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react-native project and wanted to generate the signed apk for deployment on Play store. I am following the
official documentation for this:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Building unsigned apk, works just fine.

But for signed apk, after generating "my-upload-key.keystore" and placing it in /android/app directory (inlcluding other settings as guided in docs.), whenever I run command 
"gradlew bundleRelease", it gives the following error:

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

warning: the transform cache was reset.
error The resource `Path-to-project-root-directory\index.ts` was not found.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

  > Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 39s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53295008/11212074 Please refer

Comment: Tried all answered solutions, none worked for me. Neither is there any accepted answer.