# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'

Tags: android, react-native

When I run

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

in RN 0.61.3 and I receive this error message.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'
```

The build works fine when debugging without the release variant.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

For some reason I needed to create the `assets` folder as per below.

`android/app/src/main/assets`

Comment: I created project React Native, I couldn't find the assets folder. I had to create and this worked.

Comment: Failed to open file H:\My Projects\Rannlab2\BharatDarshan020App\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle.hbc.ee6df4: no such file or directory .
This is my error and your solution is not working for me.
Do you have any solution for my problem? if you have please share

Answer (score 12):

I had the assets folder already, but mistakenly had kept on being in the android folder, I went in parent directory with

```bash
cd ..
```

then ran the following command to generate the bundle:

```bash
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Comment: I made same mistake and was worrying :D

Answer (score 8):

- Go to `android/app/src/main/`
- Create one more folder of the name `assets`
  It will look like `android/app/src/main/assets`
- Then run it. Absolutely workable.

Comment: Same solution as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58767107/2227743)

Answer (score 5):

Right click the app folder New->Folder->Assests Folder

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command:

```
npx mkdirp android/app/src/main/assets/ && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use this command：`npx mkdirp android/app/src/main/assets/ && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

Answer (score 0):

You should use this command to create assets folder in android.

Run this command in project directory.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Please use this, Its help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make **dir or folder** named as `assets`
inside `project/android/app/src/main/` **manually** or by running **command** below from root of project

```
npx mkdirp android/app/src/main/assets/
```

then run this command from root of project:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Create debug apk:

```
cd android/
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

and You will get apk here:

```
android/app/build/outputs/apk/
```