# React natives LINKING component works fine in debug but in android release doesn't response

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-linking

I want to get token by deep link to browser , every thing is ok in
debug but in release build nothing happen ,  I have checked the logcat
in android studio; here is my error in image . [My Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8z6.png)

**My environment :**

```
react native version : 0.59.9
node version : v12.14.1
npm version : 6.13.4
gradle plugin version :3.4.0
gradle version : 5.4.1
```

I have tried these steps :

1. [Turn off minified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601897/android-studio-3-5-warning-the-rule-keep-public-class-extends-androidx-vers)
2. [Resolved assets problem](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22234)
3. [Bundle assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767106/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-android-app-src-main-assets-index-andro) then ./gradlew assemblerelease
4. Also try with android studio signed build

[My Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcjKH.png)
[My LogCat Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG0hD.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to via HTTP Protocol to any URI in your production-app. It has to be HTTP**S**

Comment: Thank for your help <3 but the connection hasn't been secure yet so I can't send https request

Comment: I have done that before but " Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "

Answer (score 0):

Modify this file **android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml** file

```xml
<manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```