# android:attr/fontStyle not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

when i run ./gradlew assembleRelease on my react android project, i keep getting the following error:

```
    A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6da249295a8c8ecbd4d1ab0ef0c0da5a/core-1.5.0-alpha04/res/values/values.xml:143:5-174:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
         
     /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6da249295a8c8ecbd4d1ab0ef0c0da5a/core-1.5.0-alpha04/res/values/values.xml:143:5-174:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
         
     /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6da249295a8c8ecbd4d1ab0ef0c0da5a/core-1.5.0-alpha04/res/values/values.xml:143:5-174:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
         
     /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6da249295a8c8ecbd4d1ab0ef0c0da5a/core-1.5.0-alpha04/res/values/values.xml:143:5-174:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
         
     /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6da249295a8c8ecbd4d1ab0ef0c0da5a/core-1.5.0-alpha04/res/values/values.xml:143:5-174:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

It builds fine of i do a assembeDebug

Here is some of my gradle build settings

```
 buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'


multiDexEnabled true


release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }


apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.10'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Try deleting gradle cache and rebuilding

Comment: Where is the gradle cache? all i see is a gadle-wrapper.jar and .properties file insid ethe gralde folder in the project

Comment: In home/.gradle  or windows/user/yourName/.gradle  . There should be a caches folder inside it . it should be safe to delete . If you are worried the copy some where else and delete . .gradle folder will be hidden

Comment: You can also try deleting .gradle folder "inside project" if above didn't work

Comment: Deleted the cache file in the .gradle folder and re ran the above command and still recieved the same error

Answer (score 1):

run this command:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res --verbose`

and then delete project_root/android/app/src/main/raw + drawable-.. folders.

After that build your release APK.

Comment: When i try runing that command i get `Command `bundle` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.` i am inside my react naive project and other react native commands work fine such as 'react-native start'

Comment: That progressed and enabled me to run the script, however i now get this error:
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/haste-map-metro-4-0be85dad9d95e79ac5ef993923

Comment: I tried runing sudo npx react-native ..... but it says ocmmand npx not found after  place sudo before it

Comment: looks like user access problem, may be try `sudo chmod -R 777 {path}`.

Comment: Ok thanks. 

I now get this error :

info Writing bundle output to:, android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'

Comment: Can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767106/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-android-app-src-main-assets-index-andro

Comment: I don't have another idea, maybe sync project in android studio and try again.

Comment: No joy, even restarted my whole machine :( i dont understand why this builds and works on debug mod ebut not on release. ie ven tried to disable any proguard obfuscating

Comment: OK i have made progrss.  i had to execute that code one level down and it worked. You mention i should delete androud/app/src/main/raw+drawable folders but there is none, i have app/src/main/res/raw and draables but that contains assets used in the app?

Comment: To be honest, i do that without understanding the why, but if i dont i get duplicate assets error.

Comment: OK thanks. after i had deleted the drawabel and raw folders, i executed the assembleRelease again andi got the same android resorce linking failed errors as before :(

Comment: are you using some custom fonts? try react-native link if so. Also try to build the apk using android studio