# unable to build APK in React Native?

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I'm trying to build APK for my app and unable to build the APK file. I followed all the instructions in the Doc here. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android). 
**My react version:-**
 [image: My react version.]

**Errors:-**

[image: Errors 1]

[image: Error2]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56139615/11380693 does this help?

Comment: Yeah, I tried those steps too. "gradlew clean app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets" this code generates APK file. But after installing it in the device unable to open the app. The app stop immediately.