# Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED - React Native - Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-reanimated, release-builds, react-native-reanimated-v2

Getting this error in my React-Native app when I run on Android using `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` or generate a Release Build. I tried whatever solutions I found on Stackoverflow and GitHub like - upgrading `gradle build tools` version, modifying `babel.config.js`, clean project, `--reset-cache`, `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall, Invalidate and Restart, etc. but none of it solved. It is a blocker since I am not able to generate a build to publish.

I have provided the only stacktrace error available.

```
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
The system cannot find the path specified.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.  

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Another information I noticed is I am getting the above stacktrace when the build execution executes `:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` and reaches `react-native-animated`. I tried the solutions suggested from the similar issues reported in `react-native-animated` but that too didn't fix.

I am not able to find whether the issue is with the package or the local project setup.

Also I noticed that the package doesn't seem to be configured properly in Android. Screenshot attached below for reference. This package alone doesn't have the right arrow.

[image]

**Library versions:**

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
"react-native-reanimated": "2.1.0"
```

**Gradle info:**

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.8.1-all.zip
```

**Android Studio Version: 4.2.1**

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53295008/5918233) I found that the below line was present in my code

```
project.ext.react = [
   nodeExecutableAndArgs : ["/usr/local/bin/node"]
];
```

My other RN projects doesn't have this line but worked fine. So removing the line `nodeExecutableAndArgs : ["/usr/local/bin/node"]` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue. After struggling with it for a few hours, realised it was due to `babel`.

Upgrading `babel` to latest version helped me resolve this issue.

Hope this helps someone.