# Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Tags: react-native, signed-apk

I am getting this error which I try to create singed apk in react native

"info Done writing bundle output
info Done writing sourcemap output
info Copying 1 asset files
info Done copying assets
'E:\React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YNmg.png)

> Task :app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> "

It will be great if anyone can tell the solution for it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-Native assembleRelease fails for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513047/react-native-assemblerelease-fails-for-task-appbundlereleasejsandassets)