# React Native 0.57.1 Android Duplicate Resources

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When running `./android/gradlew assembleRelease` I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png       [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo30x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo30x.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo30x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo30x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_5.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_5.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coins_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coins_5.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coins_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coins_5.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_2.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_2.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_4.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_4.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_2.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_2.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_unlockablecharacters] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_unlockablecharacters.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_unlockablecharacters] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_unlockablecharacters.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_6.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_6.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo3x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo3x.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo3x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_trophies_cookoo3x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_3.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_happy_3.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_5.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_5.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_3.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_marilyn_monroe_emotions_blinking_3.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_mostpopularlabel] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_mostpopularlabel.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_mostpopularlabel] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_mostpopularlabel.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_4.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_4.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coins_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coins_4.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coins_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coins_4.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo30x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo30x.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo30x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo30x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_earthbg] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_earthbg.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_earthbg] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_earthbg.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_6.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_6.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry10x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry10x.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry10x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry10x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_3conversations] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_3conversations.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_3conversations] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_3conversations.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo10x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo10x.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo10x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_trophies_cookoo10x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_angry_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_angry_2.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_angry_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_angry_2.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_profile] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_profile.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_profile] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_napoleon_profile.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_4.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_emotions_happy_4.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry30x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry30x.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry30x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry30x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coins_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coins_6.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coins_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coins_6.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_6.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_blinking_6.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_bg] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_bg.jpg     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_bg] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_bg.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_2.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_2.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_3.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_3.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_4.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_4] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_4.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_2.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_2.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_allconversations1x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_allconversations1x.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_allconversations1x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_trophies_allconversations1x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_coins500] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_coins500.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_coins500] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_coinsmodal_coins500.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_3.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_angry_3.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_5.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_5] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_happy_5.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_2.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_2] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_blinking_2.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_3.png       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_3] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_emotions_cookoo_3.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry100x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry100x.png     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry100x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_einee_trophies_angry100x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_donald_trump_bg] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_donald_trump_bg.jpg       [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_donald_trump_bg] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_donald_trump_bg.jpg: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_trophies_allconversations3x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_trophies_allconversations3x.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_trophies_allconversations3x] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_cleopatra_trophies_allconversations3x.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>     [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_6.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_6] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/app_assets_images_characters_leonardo_da_vinci_emotions_angry_6.png: Error: Duplicate resources
>   ```

I already tried the following from the answers I found on [React Native Duplicate resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464842/react-native-duplicate-resources) with zero success:

**Attempt #1:**

"Deleting the drawables with rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* and generating APK on Android Studio worked for me."

**Attempt #2:**

"rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

And compile android again react-native run-android"

---

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you run react-native upgrade after installing 0.57.1?

Comment: I upgraded to 0.57.1 from 0.55.4

Comment: Yes, but it was a significant upgrade (new babel version etc) so it is advisable to run **react-native upgrade** after updating your node packages. It helped me overcome some issues.

Comment: I upgraded using react-native-git-upgrade so that has already been taken care of

Comment: It says bash: react-native-git-upgrade: command not found

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is the simple solution :

1. Delete **build** inside **android/app** folder
2. Delete **build** inside **android** folder
3. run `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/`
4. Open build.gradle --> **android/app/build.gradle**
5. comment this line

> `//apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`

6. Delete `index.android.bundle` file from assets folder and re-create using  `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
7. run `react-native run-android` **Or**
   run `react-native run-android --variant=release`

Happy Coding..

Comment: This finally worked for me. Item 5 was critical. The only difference for me was I went to the android folder and built my apk with this command: "./gradlew assembleRelease" as in the question.

Comment: Awesome! This helped me.
On step 6, I had to replace the command with `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` to avoid `The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type boolean`.
Then I ran `./gradlew assembleArRelease --stacktrace`

Comment: This solved the issue for me. But running `react-native run-android --variant=release` does not update any code changes. And deleteing the index.android.bundle (why is it even in `android/app/src/main/assets/`? seems weird) causes the build to crash instantly with this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo

Is this expected behavior? It would make that command pretty useless.

Comment: @davidnathan, after deleting index.android.bundle, generate it again and then delete or quite terminal process & run **Npm Start***  and after this run android release cmd.

Comment: I reached upto point no. 5. Since I don't have index.android.bundle, then what should I do next.?

Comment: @vicky keshri create index.android.bundle and than run

Comment: @MAhipalSingh I tried that, but again getting same error.!

Comment: I am using react-native 0.61.0. Please help me. I got stuck on this from last 4 days. Please..!

Comment: What I don't understand: building locally, I have to have these assets copied over with the bundle command, or the assets will not be present? After doing this, they still get copied over when assembleRelease... why does gradle not just skip duplicate files?

Answer (score 22):

Had the same error. What I did to resolve it:

1. delete all the pictures in the drawable folder *android/app/src/main/res*
2. generate apk *cd android && gradlew assembleRelease*

Comment: Thanks, Only deleting the drawables in the Android project helped in my case. `"react": "^16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"`, `"react-native": "^0.57.3"`, `"react-native": "^0.57.3"`, `"react-native": "^0.57.3"`, `"react-native": "^0.57.3"`, `"react-native": "^0.57.3"`.

Comment: This seems a bit extreme. How do you include images in your app then?

Comment: @Bob Images are copied into a bundle when you run the command, so if images have already been copied, running the command again would cause that error

Comment: Don't delete just the whole "res" directory, only all "drawable" folders inside. Res directory contains also "mipmap" folders which are needed by AndroidManifest.

Comment: I tried that, but again getting same. I have also added clearTextTraffice inside AndroidManifest file also. Please help, I am trying this from last 4 days.

Answer (score 9):

Recent versions of React Native (>0.57.0) have increased the Gradle wrapper level to 4.4 and Gradle plugin to 3.1.4, as indicated by the changelog. This has the effect of making the Gradle build process store the results of AAPT, which are now required, within a different directory than previously.
So basically you have to edit the /node_modules/react-native/react.gradle file
and add the doLast right after the doFirst block, manually.

```
doFirst { ... }
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

Comment: first create JS bundle by command and comment below line in `app-> build.gradle` can also resolve this problem.                                                                                          apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

Comment: How and where I have to add above snippet in my code.?

Comment: @vickykeshri have to add statically in node modules folder path given in above answer `/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle`. Apart from this we have more convenient solution to remove  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle" line in app-> build.gradle.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the `android/app/src/res/` path and then delete all the `drawable-hdpi`, `mdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi`, `raw` folders.

Answer (score 3):

llya today I have faced a similar problem and fixed by following steps:

- updated classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' to classpath 
  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' in build.gradle.
- changed distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip in /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
- Removed android.enableAapt2=false from gradle.properties
- Updated buildToolsVersion:27.0.3
- clean project
- sync gradle again in android studio.
- bundle and try again to make a release build.

Comment: Yay. This one helped me push forward. Getting other issues now but it's progress. Thanks!!

Comment: Great, happy to help

Comment: Hi Rajat. Damn it, I thought I made progress but it seems it's because I just manually deleted the duplicate images. If you can, please take a look at a new issue I made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669782/react-native-0-57-1-release-build-contains-old-code

Comment: what i should do at 'clean project' step?

Answer (score 3):

remove all files that have names like 
node_modules_{some_path}_{imagename}.{extension} or src_images_{imagename}.{extension}

from all the folders in android/app/src/main/res, e.g.

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/src_images_mylogo.jpg

The probably got put there by react-native bundle and they cause the duplicate resource error

Comment: This solved my problem! react-native bundle had already bundled all my assets so yes, I had to remove duplicates before running the assemble-release.

Answer (score 2):

I just deleted `android/app/build/generated/` folder and the build succeded.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will happen when you have 2 images with similar names and different types.

Just Check your assets and avoid naming the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the build fails after executing **Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets** you will observe this error in the subsequent attempt

The easiest way to find the duplicate entries is through version control.

If you are using Git. You can get the all the Un-tracked files using the command

> git status

& delete the files in /android/app/src/main/res/drawable** directories.

Re-run the build should work.

Answer (score 1):

The Best answer I can say is when you first build a react native app successfully you will generate some release build assets.

Delete all of them and delete the build folder in android/app/build.

And rerun npm run android.

Answer (score 0):

Remove raw file in **src/main/res/raw**

Then run This cmd=>

**npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/**

Then go run /android=> **agradlew assembleRelease**

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `android/app/build/generated/` folder and the build succeded.
I saw the same effect