# React native 0.57.1: Release build contains old code

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I run `react-native run-android --variant=release` everything works fine and the app loads but the code is a number of days old.

Reading around I found some recommendations of rebundling the app using `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` so I did.

The above code copies all my images into the `/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi` folder causing a **duplicate resources** error as such:

*[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon] /Users/Ilyakar/Documents/Business/Development/My_Projects/new/Einee/App/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources*

So for now, the only solution I came up with is to bundle the app, then to delete all the images from the **drawable-mdpi** folder. But this is not a good solution to have to do this any time I need to update the Android app.

Comment: You run ./gradlew assembleRelease first right, and then install new release? Probably you do, but i have to comment, you never know :P

Comment: More or less, yeah. Running `./gradlew assembleRelease` just outputs the apk with the old code unless I manually go through the labour of updating as shown above.

Comment: I have deleted all the drawable folder and then running the command ./gradlew assembleRelease, but again getting the same version. Please help