# Building apk duplicate giving resources error

Tags: android, react-native, build, apk

I am trying to build an apk file using android studio, and facing duplicated resources error

I have tried to delete some of duplicates but with no luck

```
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_share] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_share.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_share] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_share.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_error] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_error.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_error] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_error.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_favorite] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_favorite.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_favorite] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_favorite.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_favorited] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_favorited.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_favorited] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_favorited.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_success] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_success.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_success] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_success.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_comment] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_comment.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_comment] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_comment.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_info] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_info.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_info] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnativedropdownalert_assets_info.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_add_comment] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_add_comment.png    [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_add_comment] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_add_comment.png: Error: Duplicate resources
[drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_white_more] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_white_more.png  [drawable-xhdpi-v4/assets_images_ic_white_more] /Users/hadi/Desktop/lancer/beonews/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/assets_images_ic_white_more.png: Error: Duplicate resources
```

Comment: have you added external libraries/modules to your project?

Comment: I am using expo project, so yes I did

Comment: then please double check the resources of the expo project and your project if they contain the same resources names, this is a bug in Android studio and I think it's reported.

Comment: I've tried to delete the duplicates but when I build again android studio generated them again and makes same error ! should I rename the expo resources? but I think android studio will generate them as well !

Comment: I meant that you have to check for duplicates between expo project and your project and if there is any you have to rename them

Comment: Here is the simple solution :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245362 work for me , happy coding