# React native gradlew assembleRelease build failed. Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'

Tags: android, ios, gradle, react-native

I'm encountering with this error, when run `./gradlew assembleRelease`. I've tinkering about in some hours. Help pls. It was once builded successfully but, after my attempts of clearing something and combining different folders from my git history, nothing could rescue.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [raw/app] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/app.json [raw/app] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/app.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialcommunityicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialcommunityicons.json[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialcommunityicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialcommunityicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free_meta] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free_meta.json[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free_meta] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free_meta.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome.json[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontisto] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontisto.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontisto] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontisto.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather.json[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_feather.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_entypo] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_entypo.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_entypo] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_entypo.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_ionicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_fontawesome5free.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_simplelineicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_simplelineicons.json[raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_simplelineicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_simplelineicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_evilicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_evilicons.json [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_evilicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_evilicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialicons.json [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_materialicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_antdesign] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_antdesign.json [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_antdesign] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_antdesign.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_foundation] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_foundation.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_foundation] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_foundation.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_octicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_octicons.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_octicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_octicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_nativebase_dist_src_basic_icon_nbicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_nativebase_dist_src_basic_icon_nbicons.json [raw/node_modules_nativebase_dist_src_basic_icon_nbicons] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_nativebase_dist_src_basic_icon_nbicons.json: Error: Duplicate resources
  [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_zocial] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/src/main/res/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_zocial.json   [raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_zocial] /home/horhi/code/projects/ankilan/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/node_modules_reactnativevectoricons_glyphmaps_zocial.json: Error: Duplicate resources

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 58s
65 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 54 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this exact same errormessage today. Those are the things I have done to get the error solved. Additional, I add the things I have done previously, in case, they are correlated:

*From this related Stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55245362*

1) Deleting **/android/app/build/...**

2) Deleting **/android/build/...**

3) Comment out the line `apply from "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` in **./android/app/build.gradle**

4) Deleting **/android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.js**

5) Rebundle from Rootfolder of your project via:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output 
android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

*Here i alteret the OG answer a little, decide for yourself which way you want to use*

5) Build Releasebuild from **./android/...** via

`.\gradlew assembleRelease`

This worked for me. Other things I done before in case it still wont work for you:

- Deleting **./node_modules/...** and refetch dependencies via `npm install` or `yarn install`
- Link react-native-vector-icons via `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` from your projectroot

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried use android studio for creating apk, and that helped. I'll try this when I'll create apk again

Comment: Thanks man, All step 1 to step 4 is working, except for step 5

I run react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ to make it work.

Comment: What is the need for step#3 ?