# React Native Android version, images are suddenly missing

Tags: react-native

Both the debug version and release Android version of my React Native app are suddenly missing some images.  I've tried using

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res

from this [post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21309) over at the repo.  I created an apk less than a month ago, and this was not an issue.

The iOS version of the app works fine, with all of the images appearing.

Here is the message when I install the debug version:

> /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/gaialibrary/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:19
>   Warning:
>           application@android:allowBackup was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:9 to replace other declarations but no other
>   declaration present
>
> > Task :react-native-fbsdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java
> >     uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-google-analytics-bridge:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note:
> >     /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/android/src/main/java/com/idehub/GoogleAnalyticsBridge/ConvertToWritable.java
> >     uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-i18n:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-i18n/android/src/main/java/com/AlexanderZaytsev/RNI18n/RNI18nModule.java
> >     uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-picker/android/src/main/java/com/beefe/picker/PickerViewModule.java
> >     uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> >
> > Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details.
> >
> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/app/src/main/java/com/somethingapp/tone/Tone.java
> >     uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/app/src/main/java/com/somethingapp/fitting/OVFitting.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
> >     -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> >
> > Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug  Build somethingfittingjni x86 [1/2] Building CXX object
> >     CMakeFiles/somethingfittingjni.dir/src/main/cpp/somethingfittingjni.cpp.o
> >     [2/2] Linking CXX shared library
> >     ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libsomethingfittingjni.so
> >     Build somethingfittingjni armeabi-v7a [1/2] Building CXX object
> >     CMakeFiles/somethingfittingjni.dir/src/main/cpp/somethingfittingjni.cpp.o
> >     [2/2] Linking CXX shared library
> >     ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libsomethingfittingjni.so
> >
> > Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug  Unable to strip library
> >     '/Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libgifimage.so'
> >     due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
> >     Unable to strip library
> >     '/Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libicu_common.so'
> >     due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
> >     Unable to strip library
> >     '/Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi/libimagepipeline.so'
> >     due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.
> >
> > Task :app:installDebug  01:35:21 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config 01:35:21 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on
> >     'cee345834583458' : EOF hit. Read: -1 01:35:21 V/ddms: execute:
> >     returning Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'SM-G950N - 9' for
> >     app:debug 01:35:21 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto
> >     device 'cee345834583458' 01:35:21 D/Device: Uploading file onto device
> >     'cee345834583458' 01:35:21 D/ddms: Reading file permision of
> >     /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
> >     as: rw-r--r-- 01:35:23 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t
> >     "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 01:35:35 V/ddms: execute 'pm install
> >     -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'cee345834583458' : EOF hit. Read: -1 01:35:35 V/ddms: execute: returning 01:35:35 V/ddms: execute:
> >     running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk" 01:35:35 V/ddms: execute
> >     'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'cee345834583458' : EOF hit.
> >     Read: -1 01:35:35 V/ddms: execute: returning Installed on 1 device.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 31s

After updating the build.gradle to 3.2.1
I received the following errors:

> /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLikeViewManager.java:24:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
>                             ^   symbol:   class NonNull   location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLikeViewManager.java:25:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
>                             ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
>                             ^   symbol:   class NonNull   location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:24:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
>                             ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLoginButtonManager.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
>                             ^   symbol:   class NonNull   location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLoginButtonManager.java:24:
>   error: cannot find symbol import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
>                             ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: package androidx.annotation
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLikeViewManager.java:52:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setObjectIdAndType(RCTLikeView likeView, @Nullable ReadableMap objectIdAndType) {
>                                                             ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLikeViewManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLikeViewManager.java:61:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setLikeViewStyle(RCTLikeView likeView, @Nullable String likeViewStyle) {
>                                                           ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLikeViewManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLikeViewManager.java:66:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setAuxiliaryViewPosition(RCTLikeView likeView, @Nullable String auxiliaryViewPosition) {
>                                                                   ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLikeViewManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLikeViewManager.java:71:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setHorizontalAlignment(RCTLikeView likeView, @Nullable String horizontalAlignment) {
>                                                                 ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLikeViewManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:175:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         @Nullable ReadableMap parameters) {
>          ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBAppEventsLoggerModule
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:187:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>        public void logPushNotificationOpen(@Nullable ReadableMap payload) {
>                                             ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBAppEventsLoggerModule
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:210:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>        @Nullable
>         ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBAppEventsLoggerModule
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLoginButtonManager.java:62:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setLoginBehavior(RCTLoginButton loginButton, @Nullable String loginBehavior) {
>                                                                 ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLoginButtonManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLoginButtonManager.java:67:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       public void setDefaultAudience(RCTLoginButton loginButton, @Nullable String defaultAudience) {
>                                                                   ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLoginButtonManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLoginButtonManager.java:74:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               @Nullable ReadableArray publishPermissions) {
>                ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLoginButtonManager
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBLoginButtonManager.java:81:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               @Nullable ReadableArray readPermissions){
>                ^   symbol:   class Nullable   location: class FBLoginButtonManager Note: Some input files use or override a
>   deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note:
>   /Users/someguy/projects/third/something-app/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/Utility.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 17 errors

Comment: One of the solutions is to update Android Gradle plugin version. At least **'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'**

Comment: I tried updating, but it ended up breaking my import statements

Comment: May b you have to migrate your project to androidx.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464842/react-native-duplicate-resources) I was able to solve this issue.  Remove the generated resources/drawable folder using

```
rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
```

then generate it again using

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

I will add that this caused some issues with my splash page logo.  The only workaround was to manually add my splashpage logo to the /drawable-mdpi folder.