# adding product flavours to react native android project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-productflavors

I am trying to add flavors to an existing react native project like the following:

```
 flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    flavourone {
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.example.flavourone"
    }
     flavourtwo {
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.example.flavourtwo"
    }
}
```

But when I try to generate a signed apk, it seems like all my drawable files gets duplicated, i get:

```
Error: Duplicate resources
```

I have tried a bunch of different solutions, cleaning the project, running the commands in package.json to bundle to temp directory etc. I think the build.gradle file is not correctly configured to support adding flavors, or I am not doing it correctly.

any help would be greatly appreciated, here follows my gradle file (with few things renamed to example):

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
]

//using custom react gradle here to get around https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52464842/react-native-duplicate-resources
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-sentry/sentry.gradle"
apply from: "../react.gradle"
//apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        flavourone {
            dimension "default"
            applicationId "com.example.flavourone"
        }
         flavourtwo {
            dimension "default"
            applicationId "com.example.flavourtwo"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        debug {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res']
            // this uses the debug's res directory which contains a "debug" icon
        }

        release {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/debugRelease/java']
            // this avoids copying across code from the debugRelease java directory
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            (removed)
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86-64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
           (removed)
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86-64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  (removed)
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I use the command in package.json (`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform android --dev false --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`) before making a apk.

it seems once I run this command my default drawables conflicts with flavortwo drawables, and ends up with duplicate resources

Answer (score 0):

In android/app/src/main/res
drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi, and raw folder delete it and add in `android/app/build.gradle` file

```
android {
...    
aaptOptions {
            cruncherEnabled = false
        }
```

then  `./dradlew clean`, `invalid caches/restart` in android studio and then build signed apk.

Comment: thanks, i will try this. (not invalid caches) let me try that quickly

Comment: have tried this now, doesnt work, please check my edit on my post. I think my config is not correct, but not sure what the problem is