# React Native Error: Duplicate resources, assets coming in some screens and not coming in others in android release APK

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am building a release APK of my React Native app in Android using Gradle version `3.2.0` and `compileSdkVersion` 28. I am running the following commands:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease && ./gradlew installRelease
```

My folder structure is:

[image: Folder structure]

My `package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-native": "0.57.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-animated-icons": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-appsee": "^2.4.14",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-cast-chrome": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-cast-ui": "1.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.22.3",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-email": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^5.0.3",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-flurry-analytics": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-gridview": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-iap": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-kochava-tracker": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-orientation": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-photo-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.4",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-underline-tabbar": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-video-controls": "^2.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2",
    "react-navigation-backhandler": "^1.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-external-helpers": "^7.0.0",
    "ajv": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.0",
    "jest": "23.4.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.45.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1",
    "schedule": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

While ruuning the commands, I get error on `Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED` with `Error: Duplicate resources` for all of my assets. When removing the assets from my drawable folders, the app builds.

But while running the release APK, some of the images are not appearing at all while others are. Furthermore, the same image is appearing in some places while not appearing in others. None of these problems happen while running the debug app from the JS server. This problem is not happening in iOS.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add the folder structure you are using?

Comment: Have you tried removing the two build folder and have you checked for duplicate named images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to RN 0.57 change log:

> Android tooling has been updated to match newer configuration
>   requirements (SDK 27, gradle 4.4, and support library 27); building
>   with Android plugin 3.2 doesn't work due to the gradle scripts, so
>   please stay on Android Studio 3.1 for now

1) try to set those according to RN change log

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4` should work

2) try to remove android build folder and run just `./gradlew assembleRelease` without any bundle-ing

I am using RN 0.57 too and generating apk without bundle-ing works ok for me.

If you still have problems and want to use bundle-ing try to check:

[React Native Android Duplicate file error when generating apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084810/react-native-android-duplicate-file-error-when-generating-apk)

These answers from there should fix the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52750886/1979861

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50876742/1979861

More info about 0.57 android updates here:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: I tried this & it didn't work. I have added my project structure.

Comment: Add also your package.json dependencies to your question, at least the RN version and babel stuff

Comment: Added the package.json

Answer (score 0):

I hope this email finds you well. I wanted to share an informative blog post with you that I recently came across. Here i provide proper solution. In above example i check. Initially worked but when build upload that's time create issue.
[https://medium.com/@yourerrorbro/handling-duplicate-resource-issue-in-android-released-builds-in-react-native-f63c67176bce](https://I%20hope%20this%20email%20finds%20you%20well.%20I%20wanted%20to%20share%20an%20informative%20blog%20post%20with%20you%20that%20I%20recently%20came%20across.%20Here%20i%20provide%20proper%20solution.%20In%20above%20example%20i%20check.%20Initially%20worked%20but%20when%20build%20upload%20that%27s%20time%20create%20issue.%20%20https://medium.com/@yourerrorbro/handling-duplicate-resource-issue-in-android-released-builds-in-react-native-f63c67176bce)