# React Native : Error: Duplicate resources - Android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, react-native

I was trying to create a release apk file from Android but when I create a release apk with PNG image I'm getting `Duplicate Resource` error. Initially I thought this is happening because I made a mistake in the existing project but when I created a new project with a single `Image` component itself I'm getting the `Duplicate Resource` error. Here are the steps I followed

1. Create a app - `react-native init demo`
2. Create a assets folder in the project root folder.
3. Add a `PNG` image inside the assets folder.
4. Now implement the `Image` component with the above `PNG` image.
5. Now bundle it using the cmd

```bash
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

6. Then generate release apk using `Generate Signed APK` from `Android Studio`.

This will throw the following error:

```
[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario] /Users/jeffreyrajan/Tutorials/RN/errorCheck/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_mario.png [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario] /Users/jeffreyrajan/Tutorials/RN/errorCheck/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario.png: Error: Duplicate resources
:app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario] /Users/jeffreyrajan/Tutorials/RN/errorCheck/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/assets_mario.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario] /Users/jeffreyrajan/Tutorials/RN/errorCheck/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario.png: Error: Duplicate resources

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
```

Note: When you generate a `release apk` without any PNG image you will not get any error, it will create you the `release apk`.

Here are the other files code.

**`App.js`**

```javascript
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Image, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={require('./assets/mario.png')} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "errorCheck",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any solution for this?

**Update:**

Here are the other details

```groovy
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Tried with `Android Studio 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.1, 3.1.4 & 3.2`

Comment: did u run application using react-native run-android ?

Comment: Yes @Lucefer I don't have any problem to run the app directly using react-native run-android only thing is when I generate the release apk I'm getting the above error

Comment: what is the android studio version you are using?

Comment: Its Android Studio 3.2.1 @FlorinDobre

Comment: Check my answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52767101/1979861 Use Android studio 3.1.4 Android 3.2 has problem at building RN 0.57 projects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native assets coming in some screens and not coming in others in android release APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668524/react-native-assets-coming-in-some-screens-and-not-coming-in-others-in-android-r)

Comment: @FlorinDobre I have tried with Android Studio 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.1, 3.1.4 & 3.2 still getting the same error

Comment: please check my answer to a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066718/427622

Answer (score 134, accepted):

After trying a lot of solutions I found only Three solution is working. Here they are

**Solution 1:**

Clean the `drawable` folder from the terminal using Gradle. `cd` into the `android` folder, then run cmd `./gradlew clean`

**Solution 2:**

After bundling delete the `drawable` folder from `Android Studio`. You could find this in `android/app/src/main/res/drawable`

**Solution 3:**

> **PLEASE DO NOT USE SOLUTION #2, AS PROPOSED BY THE ORIGINAL AUTHOR!** All packages under `node_modules` are generated, and any changes you make will be lost when the `react-native` package is reinstalled / upgraded.

In this solution you no need to delete any drawable folder. Just add the following code in the **`react.gradle`** file which you could find under `node_modules/react-native/react.gradle` path

```gradle
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

For reference I will add the full **react.gradle** file code here

```gradle
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

def config = project.hasProperty("react") ? project.react : [];

def cliPath = config.cliPath ?: "node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js"
def bundleAssetName = config.bundleAssetName ?: "index.android.bundle"
def entryFile = config.entryFile ?: "index.android.js"
def bundleCommand = config.bundleCommand ?: "bundle"
def reactRoot = file(config.root ?: "../../")
def inputExcludes = config.inputExcludes ?: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
def bundleConfig = config.bundleConfig ? "${reactRoot}/${config.bundleConfig}" : null ;


afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { def variant ->
        // Create variant and target names
        def targetName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def targetPath = variant.dirName

        // React js bundle directories
        def jsBundleDir = file("$buildDir/generated/assets/react/${targetPath}")
        def resourcesDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetPath}")

        def jsBundleFile = file("$jsBundleDir/$bundleAssetName")

        // Additional node and packager commandline arguments
        def nodeExecutableAndArgs = config.nodeExecutableAndArgs ?: ["node"]
        def extraPackagerArgs = config.extraPackagerArgs ?: []

        def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(
            name: "bundle${targetName}JsAndAssets",
            type: Exec) {
            group = "react"
            description = "bundle JS and assets for ${targetName}."

            // Create dirs if they are not there (e.g. the "clean" task just ran)
            doFirst {
                jsBundleDir.deleteDir()
                jsBundleDir.mkdirs()
                resourcesDir.deleteDir()
                resourcesDir.mkdirs()
            }

            doLast {
                def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
                    File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
                    if (originalDir.exists()) {
                        File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
                        ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
                    }
                }
                moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
            }

            // Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result
            inputs.files fileTree(dir: reactRoot, excludes: inputExcludes)
            outputs.dir jsBundleDir
            outputs.dir resourcesDir

            // Set up the call to the react-native cli
            workingDir reactRoot

            // Set up dev mode
            def devEnabled = !(config."devDisabledIn${targetName}"
                || targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release"))

            def extraArgs = extraPackagerArgs;

            if (bundleConfig) {
                extraArgs = extraArgs.clone()
                extraArgs.add("--config");
                extraArgs.add(bundleConfig);
            }

            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine("cmd", "/c", *nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, *extraArgs)
            } else {
                commandLine(*nodeExecutableAndArgs, cliPath, bundleCommand, "--platform", "android", "--dev", "${devEnabled}",
                    "--reset-cache", "--entry-file", entryFile, "--bundle-output", jsBundleFile, "--assets-dest", resourcesDir, *extraArgs)
            }

            enabled config."bundleIn${targetName}" ||
                config."bundleIn${variant.buildType.name.capitalize()}" ?:
                targetName.toLowerCase().contains("release")
        }

        // Expose a minimal interface on the application variant and the task itself:
        variant.ext.bundleJsAndAssets = currentBundleTask
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedResFolders = files(resourcesDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)
        currentBundleTask.ext.generatedAssetsFolders = files(jsBundleDir).builtBy(currentBundleTask)

        // registerGeneratedResFolders for Android plugin 3.x
        if (variant.respondsTo("registerGeneratedResFolders")) {
            variant.registerGeneratedResFolders(currentBundleTask.generatedResFolders)
        } else {
            variant.registerResGeneratingTask(currentBundleTask)
        }
        variant.mergeResources.dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

        // packageApplication for Android plugin 3.x
        def packageTask = variant.hasProperty("packageApplication")
            ? variant.packageApplication
            : tasks.findByName("package${targetName}")

        def resourcesDirConfigValue = config."resourcesDir${targetName}"
        if (resourcesDirConfigValue) {
            def currentCopyResTask = tasks.create(
                name: "copy${targetName}BundledResources",
                type: Copy) {
                group = "react"
                description = "copy bundled resources into custom location for ${targetName}."

                from resourcesDir
                into file(resourcesDirConfigValue)

                dependsOn(currentBundleTask)

                enabled currentBundleTask.enabled


            }

            packageTask.dependsOn(currentCopyResTask)
        }

        def currentAssetsCopyTask = tasks.create(
            name: "copy${targetName}BundledJs",
            type: Copy) {
            group = "react"
            description = "copy bundled JS into ${targetName}."

            if (config."jsBundleDir${targetName}") {
                from jsBundleDir
                into file(config."jsBundleDir${targetName}")
            } else {
                into ("$buildDir/intermediates")
                into ("assets/${targetPath}") {
                    from jsBundleDir
                }

                // Workaround for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2+ new asset directory
                into ("merged_assets/${targetPath}/merge${targetName}Assets/out") {
                    from jsBundleDir
                }
            }

            // mergeAssets must run first, as it clears the intermediates directory
            dependsOn(variant.mergeAssets)

            enabled currentBundleTask.enabled
        }

        packageTask.dependsOn(currentAssetsCopyTask)
    }
}
```

Credit:
[ZeroCool00](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22234#issuecomment-437657528)
[mkchx](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22234#issuecomment-437812451)

Comment: @Jeffrey-Rajan - I wanted to give you (along with ZeroCool00 and mkchx) credit as the inspiration for a PR I made to react-native which was just recently merged -  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/962437fafd02c936754d1e992479056577cafd05 - I extended your proposed patch above to handle flavors, and it's on react-native@master now, so hopefully this won't bite people in the future.

Comment: Seems extreme to me to modify a React file (`node_modules` folder cough cough...). Make sure you look into your own setup before going with rogue solutions. Could be as simple as: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49589616/925307

Comment: Please DO NOT use Solution #2. Developers should not be editing code in `node_modules`, as the packages installed in this folder are generated, and added code will be overwritten / lost when the package is upgraded / uninstalled.

Comment: Solution 2 makes my icons disappear

Comment: Is there any way to use solution 1 without deleting all the folders? I need them for the notification icons

Comment: I also am using the drawable folders for resources on the native part (notification icons, launcher layouts, launch icons, etc). 

What worked for me is not deleting the whole drawable* folders but only delete the files inside that start with prefix "node_modules" (assets from the dependencies) and "src_" (assets from your project) and then assemble release just as usual.

Comment: Just wondering, if it was auto-generated, why make it an error in the first place?

Comment: That seems to be working. Note: you may need to add "raw" to that list.

Answer (score 167):

(UPDATED)

This solution works for me

```
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*

rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw
```

In my case, the build failed because there are duplicated resources in my Android project (in Android folder), these two lines are necessary to remove duplicated resources, that's all.

Comment: an explanation of how/why this solves the problem would make this a better answer...

Comment: This looks like this just deletes your assets.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried react-native bundle ... again after this and got the same error when trying to build.

Comment: what if i am using assets in there? i am not sure why i ahve to delete stuff inside?

Comment: WHy do we have to delete these directories? these are valid directries for assets needed in the nativ android project. if i delete this then any layouts that use these drawables are broken

Comment: @Jonathan, Why you need to put assets in your android directory? Assets are added in you src directory.

Comment: The asset directory is inside src

Comment: @Jonathan, Of course, but these lines remove duplicated resources in android directory not in your src directory

Comment: i heard you have to completely remove the folders

Comment: Yes, but images are recreated by React Native when you rebuild the project, and ithe build failed when these resources are presents, that's why I need to delete them before a new build

Comment: @DrCord that just remove the folders.

Comment: One of my react project works well but the another one has the problem. This may be not the general  solution as it works.

Comment: Removing `drawable-*` worked and fixed the issue. For us deleting `/raw` caused the build to fail. We had two ssl certs in there that did not get copied over automatically on next build.

Comment: You can find dublications by looking in `res` folder no need to delete all drawables may be your app need some of theme

Comment: Also next time you want to build, if you omit ` --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` from the following command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` you won't get the error.

Comment: this command does not work on windows

Answer (score 71):

**For generating debug apk**

```json
"debug-build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd .."
```

**For generating release apk**

```json
"release-build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/ && rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-* && rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/raw/* && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .."
```

*Works fine for my **react-native >= 0.61.2** project by using the above code on my **scripts** section of **package.json** file.*

Comment: This approach should be the accepted answer. However, you might be able to use `./gradlew clean` instead.

Comment: windows
`"debug-build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && cd app/src/main/res/ && rmdir /S /Q raw && rmdir /S /Q drawable-mdpi"`


`"release-build": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd .."`

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer will work, however it does not take into account that modifying a node package means that if you update your change will be lost (as well as being against best-practices, you should extend the module somehow).

This is originally from [React-native android release error: duplicate resource](https://medium.com/@locnv/react-native-android-release-error-duplicate-resource-460c4a1b91bd)

1. Create folder `fixAndroid` in the `android` folder of your project (`{project-root}/android/fixAndroid`).
2. Create file `android-gradle-fix` in the `fixAndroid` folder of your project (`{project-root}/android/fixAndroid/android-gradle-fix`).

```groovy
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}")
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}-v4")
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir)
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}

// Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result
```

3. Create file `android-release-fix.js` in the `fixAndroid` folder you created:

```js
const fs = require('fs')

try {
    var curDir = __dirname
    var rootDir = process.cwd()

    var file = `${rootDir}/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle`
    var dataFix = fs.readFileSync(`${curDir}/android-gradle-fix`, 'utf8')
    var data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')

    var doLast = "doLast \{"
    if (data.indexOf(doLast) !== -1) {
        throw "Already fixed."
    }

    var result = data.replace(/\/\/ Set up inputs and outputs so gradle can cache the result/g, dataFix);
    fs.writeFileSync(file, result, 'utf8')
    console.log('Android Gradle Fixed!')
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

4. Add script to package.json scripts section:

```json
"postinstall": "node ./android/fixAndroid/android-release-fix.js"
```

This will find and insert content of “android-gradle-fix” file into node_modules/react-native/react.gradle.

5. Run `npm install` from the root of your project.
6. Run `rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*` from the root of your project.

*Now you can bundle the release with either React Native at the console or Android Studio:*

**React Native command line**

```bash
cd {project-root}/android
./gradlew/bundleRelease
```

**Android Studio**

1. Open folder android in Android Studio and build project.
2. Select Build/Generate signed APK to build release.

Answer (score 12):

1. Delete **drawable-xxx** folders
2. Delete **raw**

inside **src -> main -> res** folder then

3. run this command in terminal:

react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res_temp

4. then generate signed apk using keystore, alias and passwords using terminal or android studio

Comment: can you explain what the script in point no.3 does?

Answer (score 10):

who are facing the same issue in RN!
I think it's absolutely awful that this issue stands here for so long time already, but I want to share the way to solve it after investigation of different solutions.

Jeffrey Rajan is absolutely right about the possible solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53260522/1611414

I think it's super bad to change `react.gradle` file in `node_modules` and it leads to many many different issues with the maintenance of this RN project. So I would recommend to chose the first option - to use bash command to remove that folder before running build.

I want to share what I've done in my project and maybe you can reuse the same approach:

In `./package.json`:

```json
scripts: {
   "build": "react-native bundle --platform android 
             --dev false
             --entry-file index.js
             --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
             --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
          && rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/
          && rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw/",

   "release": "yarn build && cd ./android && ./gradlew bundleRelease"
}
```

and the release is running by doing `yarn release`.

These lines are important:

```bash
&& rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/
&& rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw/
```

they remove duplicated resources from the `build` step before `bundleRelease` is running. The solution is tested with RN 0.57, 0.58, 0.59 and 0.60

Enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

for latest version of React-Native and gradle, you don't need to bundle your assets. Once you are done with the code, just cd into the android folder and run:

```bash
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

The assets are automatically bundled while the above command is been executed. The duplicate resources error shows up because you have explicitly bundled before and running the above command bundles again hence the error.

Answer (score 7):

tolotrasmile's answer worked for me.

I included it in my little bash script that I run whenever I want to build & install Android

```bash
cd "$PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
react-native bundle \
  --platform android \
  --dev false \
  --entry-file index.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
cd ..

rm -rf "$PROJECT_DIRECTORY"/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
rm -rf "$PROJECT_DIRECTORY"/android/app/src/main/res/raw

cd "$PROJECT_DIRECTORY"/android/
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
cd ../../

adb install -r "$PROJECT_DIRECTORY"/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it worked after adding a few lines to [Jaffrey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856245/jeffrey-rajan) Answer

```groovy
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()

    File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/raw");
    if (originalDir.exists()) {
        File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/raw");
        ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

was error with release build `/android/app/src/main/res/raw/app.json`:

> [raw/app]
> /android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/app.json: Error: Duplicate resources

deleted `/android/app/src/main/res/raw/app.json`
then ran `./gradlew clean` in `android` folder
and then ran `./gradlew bundleRelease`

Answer (score 3):

For me it was a cache issue. The following command worked for me

cd into android folder

Run ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 3):

Try to use another directory for assets destination (for example res_temp).

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res_temp
```

I am also adding res_temp in gitignore.
Tested in Gradle 6.0.1 and RN 0.62.2

Answer (score 2):

My version react native is: 0.66.3 , I had fix trought commands:

```
rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*

rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/raw
```

Then run :

```
./gradlew clean
```

Finally: Generate Signed Bundle from Android Studio and works.

Answer (score 2):

This solution we work for user who are using github or any other version control system.

The reason for this issue was github. if we clean the project then and create a release build it was crashing due to missing resources.  on the other hand if i run this command.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/ && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..
```

it well create the issue duplicate resources.

so before creating a release version of your appplication.  clean you project with commad `gradlew clean` and delete the file  `android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle` . now run this commnad

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

after running this command open vs code and delete all the newly added files except `index.android.bundle`

now you can create a release of you app. it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**.
I just clean `gradlew` and starts working **no need to change** anything in.
**`/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle`**

**Steps**
1)  cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
2) react-native run-android

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
}
```

Comment: it's only release problem not debug

Answer (score 1):

I am using react-native 0.63.2. I also faced this issue and tried editing react.gradle, deleted resources/drawable and all. But at last cleaning gradle and running the command `gradlew assembleRelease` worked.

I didn't run the react-native bundle command separately. `gradlew assembleRelease` is running the react-native bundle and building apk itself.

Answer (score 1):

Spent ages on this! None of the proposed solutions were an immediate fix for me.

So I moved out all the dirs that were getting mentioned in the "duplicate resource" error message:

```
mv ./android/app/src/main/res/drawabl* /tmp

mv ./android/app/src/main/res/raw /tmp
```

then I ran a

```
./gradlew clean
```

then I ran a build:

```
/gradlew bundleRelease
```

the build was giving me a couple of errors along the lines of 'could not find a specific file in a specific place', so for each of these files I found them in the tmp/drawable folders and copied them to the exact path that the error message said it expected them to be e.g (you'll have to customise this according to the error message you get):

```
cp /tmp/drawable-mdpi/launch_screen.png app/src/main/res/drawable/
```

then:

```
./gradlew clean

/gradlew bundleRelease
```

And it finally buily successfully

Answer (score 1):

for me go to dir:
android/app/src/main/assets/fonts

check .ttf files you expect, delete .ttf of vector icons

Answer (score 1):

I had also this problem and to solve it, I have deleted resource folders and used `gradlew clean`.

I ended up with this Windows cmd script for compiling my app:

```
@echo off

call react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

rmdir android\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi /s/q
rmdir android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi /s/q
rmdir android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi /s/q
rmdir android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxhdpi /s/q
rmdir android\app\src\main\res\drawable-xxxhdpi /s/q
rmdir android\app\src\main\res\raw /s/q

cd android
call gradlew clean
REM call gradlew assembleRelease
call gradlew bundle
cd ..

dir /o:d android\app\build\outputs\apk\release
dir /o:d android\app\build\outputs\bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Good day all. It may be late but I encountered a strange situation while bundling/assembling my project on RN (0.71.x). Using the information from your project asset [drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario].

I discovered that when bundling, the configuration removes the extensions reference from the filename. So if you have **assets_mario.jpg** and **assets_mario.png** being bundled, the final configuration reference for both becomes **[drawable-mdpi-v4/assets_mario]** with two instances and thus, duplicate resources violation.

Somehow, all your assets must have unique names. Check on this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 It should work. RN 0.57 has problem with building in 3.2

This question is a possible duplicate of:

[React Native Error: Duplicate resources, assets coming in some screens and not coming in others in android release APK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668524/react-native-assets-coming-in-some-screens-and-not-coming-in-others-in-android-r/52767101#52767101)

If it still doesn't work try to use RN 0.57.2, I am using it and creating releases works very well with these deps:

```
   "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.2",
    .......
  }

  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    .....
}
```

Gradle deps:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.0.0"
```

App gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.burda.buntede"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
```

Gradle wrapper props:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

Comment: I tried with Android Studio 3.1 still I'm getting the same problem. Also this is not the duplicate question. I have updated my question with additional details as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the files you might have on:

android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/
android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/
Run Build again, This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

So basically edit the /node_modules/react-native/react.gradle file
and add the doLast right after the doFirst block, manually.

```
doFirst { ... }
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

Comment: Do not edit code in the `node_modules` folder - packages in this folder are generated, and when the package is upgraded, reinstalled, etc - the code changes will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions like patching the react.gradle file may work but they are just workarounds. The real solution lies in figuring out the problem.

1. If its only happening while creating release build then chances are you're bundling separately. If you're upgrading from older versions of react native which didn't have a react.gradle file you'd have to bundle separately and then do 'cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease' but with the introduction of react.gradle the bundling process has now been taken care by the react.gradle file, so don't bundle separately just run 'cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease' to build the release apk.
2. If this happens in debug also then chances are some generated assets or all of the generated assets have been pushed and currently reside in your directory. So i would suggest just delete all of them from the respective directory and if they are tracked by git try adding them back one by one. We had some assets starting with src_assets_blahblah which we had to delete since they were already getting generated during the build process.

Answer (score 0):

**None of the suggested solutions works for me**

In my case it was related to `.gradle` folder. Before getting this error i have moved the folder to another disk, but some files failed to copy to the destination folder.

I just cut the old folder and merge it with the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **raw** directory was containing some duplicates. So, I have to add a different function for that as well, name of added function is **moveFuncRaw** below worked perfectly for me.

```
        doLast {

            // Address issue #22234 by moving generated resources into build dir so they are in one spot, not duplicated
                def moveFuncRaw = { dirName ->
                    File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/${dirName}");
                    if (originalDir.exists()) {
                        File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/${dirName}");
                        ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
                    }
                }
                
                // Address issue #22234 by moving generated resources into build dir so they are in one spot, not duplicated
                def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
                    File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
                    if (originalDir.exists()) {
                        File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
                        ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
                    }
                }
                moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
                moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
                moveFuncRaw.curry("raw").call()
        }
```

One more thing to realize that **doLast** do not gets called every time as there could be some conditions on it like in my case there were, so you have to call separately to get it executed.

Answer (score 0):

If the above answers are not working and if the issue is similar to the below error

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
ERROR: [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnative_libraries_newappscreen_components_logofgdsfsdfsdfds] 
/Users/emmsdan/Repo/untitledApp/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnative_libraries_newappscreen_components_logofgdsfsdfsdfds.png 
[drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnative_libraries_newappscreen_components_logofgdsfsdfsdfds]
/Users/emmsdan/Repo/untitledApp/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/
node_modules_reactnative_libraries_newappscreen_components_logofgdsfsdfsdfds.png: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
```

Not the most elegant solution but this worked for me.

Delete this

> rm -rf rmnode_modules/react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen

I had similar issues, even on a newly created react-native app.
Deleting NewAppScreen and everywhere it was called fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer's solution 1 will work but it will add some more things to your assets.

Solution 1:

```
Clean the drawable folder from the terminal using Gradle. cd into the android folder, then run cmd ./gradlew clean
```

This will solve the initial problem of old code rendering but will create another issue usually: the issue of duplicate resources.

Check your androids res folder there will be added additional assets in your mipmap filders and res folder, delete all the additional added assets from the folders and run the release version of app ad you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes after you run `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

So only thing you want to do is remove the resources files which builds with it.

If you use `git`,
stage `index.android.bundle` and discard other new resource files.

Answer (score 0):

A slight addition: sometimes you end up with a "raw" in the resources folder. That has to go too.
So a slight modification to the existing react.gradle script:

```
doLast {
  def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/${resSuffix}");
if (originalDir.exists()) {
  File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/${resSuffix}");
  ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
}
  }

  moveFunc.curry("drawable-ldpi").call()
  moveFunc.curry("drawable-mdpi").call()
  moveFunc.curry("drawable-hdpi").call()
  moveFunc.curry("drawable-xhdpi").call()
  moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxhdpi").call()
  moveFunc.curry("drawable-xxxhdpi").call()
  moveFunc.curry("raw").call()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open android studio and check `res` and `res(generated)` folders. For me in `res` folder was duplicated files in `raw` folder.
I manually deleted `raw` folder from `res` and see BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score -1):

**By adding this is in /node_modules/react-native/react.gradle**

After DoFirst Paste This Code

```
doLast {
def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
    File originalDir = file("$buildDir/generated/res/react/release/drawable-${resSuffix}");
    if (originalDir.exists()) {
        File destDir = file("$buildDir/../src/main/res/drawable-${resSuffix}");
        ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir);
    }
}
moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
```

}

Comment: Do not edit code in the `node_modules` folder - packages in this folder are generated, and when the package is upgraded, reinstalled, etc - the code changes will be lost.

Answer (score -1):

It's not needed to add any code in the react-native module.

By default, the app/build.gradle set the property `bundleInRelease` as true. This means that if you run the `react native bundle` before the build, you will get this error.

To fix this issue, make sure that your app/build.gradle has the following code:

```
project.ext.react = [
   bundleInRelease: false
]
```

You can find more details in: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md

Answer (score -1):

**don't remove all element** inside drawable folders , because sometimes you have you splash screen or app icon inside this folder , so the best solution is to remove just generated images (that begins with node_modules---.png or src--.png) ;
**so you need to run just this command from the android folder of your app** :

```
rm -rf  app/src/main/res/draw*/src*.png 
rm -rf  app/src/main/res/draw*/node*.png
```

Answer (score -4):

I encountered the same problem after using 0.57.7,
Look at the `node_modules/react-native/react.gradle` file,
The resource output directory is `$buildDir/generated/res/react/${targetPath}` .
Look at the address from the log as `app/build/generated/res/react/release`,

Command
`React-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src /main/res/`

The resource output directory is 
`android/app/src/main/res/`

The problem is here.

I solved this:

1. Delete duplicate files in `android/app/res`
   (If your resources are imported from React Native, you can directly delete the directory under res).
2. Delete the `App/build` folder.
3. Will `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/ App/src/main/res/`

change into
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

No longer specify `--assets-dest`
Run command

4. Use Android Studio's `Generate Signed APK` to package properly.

the above