# React Native local assets images not showing some time on release mode

Tags: android, react-native

My local assets images are working fine on `Debug` mode. but when i build apk in `release` mode with command `react-native run-android --variant=release` at first all local images showing correct but after sometime while using app some image not showing and some are fine.
i fix this issue by add `android:largeHeap="true"` this line in `AndroidManifest.xml` but this reduce app performance. can anyone help me how can i handle this problem?

Issue is on android i didn't test this on ios.

React Info:

```
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
react-native: 0.61.2 => 0.61.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

to see if your images are present in the generated release apk in the outputs folder. If so, then your release shouldn't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bundle all your **assets** before release **apk** file using this code:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

After that move to your **android** folder and make **release** build using this:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

If the above answers didn't help you try to run this all in one code inside your project root folder

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: it show me error
`
Task `:app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/raw/app.json: Error: Duplicate resources`

Comment: So that is issue with your assets are being duplicated - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239705/react-native-error-duplicate-resources-android

Comment: issue fixed by building apk with `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` this command. without this `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`
i will also try with `./gradlew clean` thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

**if you have index.android.js in the project root then run:**

```
npx react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

**if you have index.js in the project root then run:**

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```