# Duplicate resources error on Android when running fastlane in CircleCI

Tags: android, react-native, circleci, fastlane

I'm receiving the error **duplicate resources** when I run the command below in the CircleCI:

```
react-native bundle
```

app:mergePrototypeReleaseResources is the failed task and the message below says the error is duplicated resources.

> xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon.png [drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon]
> /home/circleci/react_project/android/app/build/generated/res/react/prototype/release/drawable-xxxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_drawer_src_views_assets_toggledrawericon.png: Error: Duplicate resources

The project contains Gradle 7.6 and React 18.

These images are not in the project. They are created only in the build folder.

I tried the [React Native : Error: Duplicate resources - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239705/react-native-error-duplicate-resources-android) alternatives, but they did not work. What else should I try?