# Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle (Linux)

Tags: android, react-native

I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961021/3257598) steps to generate unsigned apk file.
Actually I managed to successfully generate the apk file and when I copy it to my device install and run it, I get red screen with an error:

> unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle

Can someone help me what is wrong?

ps. I found kind of similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows), albeit it was for windows, but the suggestion in the answer (highest voted one) uses different commands to generate apk file compared to the one I used before(my first link), so I am not sure I should follow that advice.

Comment: Dont you think you should post the code that causes that error?

Comment: Probably you are using a React Native Version more updated, try this line react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
the original one had word  index.android.js,  Im sure you have all in 1 index.js