# Rebuild native Android code in React Native

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create native Java package for my simple React Native application.

I created project with `react-native init`, added some screens and `react-navigation`.

After that I followed [The Toast Module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html).

My phone is connected via USB and every React code runs perfectly but Java code not.

In one screen in `render()` method I added simple

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { NativeModules } from "react-native"

export default class TestScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(NativeModules, NativeModules.ToastModule)

        return (
            // something
        )
    }
}
```

In result of this code I got object with all native modules provided by React Native and `undefined` value for my personal module.

I go to file `android/app/src/main/java/com/myproject/MainApplication.java` and replace `getPackages()` method into this

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList( // Disable all modules for example
        // new MainReactPackage(),
        // new ManagerPackage()
    );
}
```

Normally both packages are uncommented.

After that I tried to run application on my phone

```
$ react-native run-android --deviceId MYDEVICEID
```

Some part of console output is

```
Building the app...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s
52 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 50 up-to-date
```

Application starts but I got same result for `console.log(...)` - object and `undefined` values.

When I executed

```
$ cd android/
$ ./gradlew clean
$ cd ..
$ react-native run-android --deviceId ...
```

I got error that file under `app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk` not exists.

When I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36961021/3936476) answer I also had to copy `android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk` file into `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk`.

It's not solves my problem - my native module is not working when I uncomment my package in `MainApplication.java` file and also I cannot disable `MainReactPackage`.

My question is: how to successfully can I rebuild my project (including Java files for Android build)?

Comment: Too bad this question does not have an answer. I am going through the same crap right now. So frustrating. Followed the tutorial to the key from the React Native site and can't get anything to work.