# How to build debug apk in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]I want to build unsigned apk or debug apk. My application is successfully running on localhost. I have tried different methods. But it shows the error. I have got the answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283959/build-and-install-unsigned-apk-on-device-without-the-development-server/35286546) . when applying the command

```
 react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

It showing the error is

```
Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["D:\\workspace\\reactjs\\native\\myapp5"]
```

Then i have change index.android.js to App.js

Then it will showing the error is

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\workspace\reactjs\native\myapp5\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\index.android.bundle'
```

How to solve this problem? Please help me.

My react native versions are react-native-cli: 2.0.1 , react-native: 0.52.0 . Screenshot of my root folder i have posted.

when i run `gradlew assembleDebug` in android folder it showing the error.

[image]

Comment: please confirm index.android.js exist in your root, it might be index.js not index.android.js in newer version of react-native,

Comment: index.js is not found in root folder. App.js is available in root folder.

Comment: can you share screenshot of your root directory

Comment: i have posted the screenshot. pls chck it.

Comment: where is your entry file index.android.js ?

Comment: index.android.js is not in project when i create.

Answer (score 22):

In your root project directory

Ensure you already have a directory `android/app/src/main/assets/`. If not already there, create a directory.

After that create a new file and save it as `index.android.bundle` and put your file in like this `android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle`

After that has been done, run the following command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

and finally, run the following command.

`cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug`

then you can get apk `app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

Comment: This is the correct solution latest react native SDK. Worked well on 0.55.9

Comment: Worked as of `March 2023`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that you do not seem to have the entry file you have specified for react native bundle:

> index.android.js

Replace it with your project's entry file index.js or app.js according to your project structure.

Update:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file <your-entry-file> --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug
```

Create debug build:

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Your apk will be at `android/app/build/outputs/apk`

Comment: I have used app.js. Then it shows the error is " ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\workspace\reactjs\native\myapp5\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\index.android.bundle' "

Comment: @Joe I updated my answer. replace your entry file name with <your-entry-file>

Comment: showing the same error. " ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\workspace\reactjs\native\myapp5\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\index.android.bundle"

Comment: @Joe can you post the output of 
cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: The output is " The system cannot find the path specified. "

Comment: if you are using windows it's cd android && gradlew assembleDebug

Comment: you just have to go to the android folder and run gradlew assembleDebug on a terminal. post a screenshot if you get a error

Comment: Thanks @HDevan i understand. But when running gradlew assembleDebug. it showing a error i have posted the screenshot below question.

Comment: As per the screenshot It seems like the package "lottie-react-native" is causing the failure. Anyhow I believe you resolved the issue.

Comment: @Joe if it did solve the issue please mark as answer.

Comment: I am not solve the issue. How to solve the error that shown on screen shot

Comment: As I said the issue seems to be on using lottie-react-native package. Remove any usage of that package and see if the app builds then.

Answer (score 2):

In the root folder of your project, run the following command:

**For RN Old Version:**

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && 
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js 
--bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
--assets-dest android/app/src/main/res 
&& cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleDebug && cd ../
```

**For RN New Version:**

```
mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && 
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js 
--bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle 
--assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && 
cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleDebug && cd ../
```

The apk is generated in following folder:

**app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk**

And if you want to run the apk on simulator. Run the following command:

```
react-native run-android --variant=debug
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work..

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug
```