# error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

In react-native, I am trying to generate signed APK following their [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html). But when I execute this `./gradlew assembleRelease` command it shows me this error. [Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Iudn.png).

**My platform:**

- OS: Windows 10
- node: 8.9.1
- npm: 5.5.1
- react: 16.3.2
- react-native: 0.55

Can anybody tell me, why I am getting this error?

**I got a solution [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2837#issuecomment-371942183) by adding `android.enableAapt2=false` into `android/gradle.properties`.** Apparently, I read that it's only a temporary solution. No way to solve it with others solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283959/build-and-install-unsigned-apk-on-device-without-the-development-server might help.

Comment: @Rishabh Bhatia, Thank you. I will try it now.

Comment: @Rishabh Bhatia, Using this link I can create debug APK, but same error happens when I try to create the release APK.

Comment: This is an error with the Gradle version. You can use the lower version 2.3.3 but that's not a permanent solution either...

Comment: I have the same issue, have you managed to make it working?

Comment: @loveNZ Yes. The answer is already in my question details. Read my question details correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is only the current solution.

Comment: this is still an issue! non of the above issues on github work, even though they are all closed.. this is unbelievable, can't create out of the box apk. ps: `android.enableAapt2=false` does not work for me

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? If yes, please post it.

Comment: @atitpatel It's current solution is adding `android.enableAapt2=false` into `android/gradle.properties`. There is no other solution i find yet.

Comment: have you solve this. when i use this `android.enableAapt2=false` it create apk successfully but with blank white screen.

Comment: @AnuragShrivastava Yes. I have solved using `android.enableAapt2=false`. But don't have any issue like you. 
I thing you are having different issue. Make sure your android app is running on real device at debug mode.

Comment: no i get white screen in release mode, debug is fine.

Comment: @Arif it does not work for me

Comment: android.enableAapt2=false, I can't see any image in my app

Answer (score 5):

Add `org.gradle.configureondemand=true` to `android/gradle.properties`

Comment: I would not recommend using this. Because of RN Documentation says: ```Note: Make sure gradle.properties does not include org.gradle.configureondemand=true as that will make the release build skip bundling JS and assets into the APK.```. (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-apk)