# Failed to generate apk due to error "error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.."

Tags: react-native, gradle, apk

I'm attempting to generate a signed APK for my react-native project.  I've received the error message error: "uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.."

How do I resolve this issue?  I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076924/error-uncompiled-png-file-passed-as-argument-must-be-compiled-first-into-flat) and have also tried adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

I have also tried manually creating a debug build as instructed [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283959/build-and-install-unsigned-apk-on-device-without-the-development-server)

Finally, I noticed that there's a key component missing in the rn [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

The first step is to

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

However, I did not see anywhere about specifying the location for the my-release-key.keystore file.  I was not able to get this to work until I used

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore d:\my_private_key.keystore -alias my_key_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

should be placed inside gradle.properties NOT gradle-wrapper.properties!

Comment: This was not enough for me, but **this** was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397028/4884617