# generating apk in react-native

Tags: react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to generate my first .apk and facing error from past few days.
I search ans on stack overflow and github to but nothing helped.
By instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283959/build-and-install-unsigned-apk-on-device-without-the-development-server) **i am able to build debug release** but when when run `gradlew assembleRelease` i am getting errors

> **E:\p1\placementScript\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigationstack_dist_views_assets_backicon.png:**
>   error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first
>   into .flat file.. error: failed parsing overlays.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
>     Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

**package.json**

```
 {
   ....
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-fcm": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^2.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.12.1"
  }

   ....
}
```

and **android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 26
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

and **android/app/build.gradle**

```
...
defaultConfig {
 ...
        }
          signingConfigs {
            release {
                if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                    storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }
        }
        splits {
        ...
```

Any other file you want me to upload please ask.

**PS:- I have lot of .png files in my src folder (where all .js/etc files are) and do i need to specify some where that they are my assets**

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly common problem. Check out this thread in the RN issues with potential solutions:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19211

A solution that worked for me was to

Add the following code to file node_modules/react-native/react.gradle :

```
doLast {
    def moveFunc = { resSuffix ->
        File originalDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}")
        if (originalDir.exists()) {
            File destDir = file("${resourcesDir}/drawable-${resSuffix}-v4")
            ant.move(file: originalDir, tofile: destDir)
        }
    }
    moveFunc.curry("ldpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("mdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("hdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxhdpi").call()
    moveFunc.curry("xxxhdpi").call()
}
```

inside `def currentBundleTask = tasks.create(...`

Comment: @RajanLagah, have you tried cleaning your build before rebuilding it?

Comment: do you mean `gradlew clean` ?

Comment: @Ariel_Salem I have lot of .png files in my src folder (where all .js/etc files are) and do i need to specify some where that they are my assets

Comment: yes, did you run `gradlew clean`? I'd try out some of the solutions in the issues thread and see what works