# Build failed react-native in windows but run fine on developement mode

Tags: react-native, build, gradlew

I am working on a `react-native` project and it is working fine on development mode (running via `react-native run-android`) but when I tried to generate unsigned APK using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283959/build-and-install-unsigned-apk-on-device-without-the-development-server) link I got some `errors` which I showed below.

I followed the first comment and it is to run this command on root of my project.

```
react-native bundle --dev false --platform android --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/index.android.bundle
--assets-dest ./android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debu
```

and when it finished run this command in android directory.

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

But when I run `gradlew assembleDebug` command I got following errors.

> error: resource
>   android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored
>   not found. error: resource
>   android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
>   C:\Users\Habib M.
>   Farooq.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\96831bdc0a7a4525ff0542204eea37bf\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>
> C:\Users\Habib M.
>   Farooq.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\96831bdc0a7a4525ff0542204eea37bf\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13:
>   AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
>
> C:\Users\Habib M.
>   Farooq.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\96831bdc0a7a4525ff0542204eea37bf\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:17:5-93:
>   AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster'
>   not found.
>
> C:\Users\Habib M.
>   Farooq.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\96831bdc0a7a4525ff0542204eea37bf\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
>
> C:\Users\Habib M.
>   Farooq.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\96831bdc0a7a4525ff0542204eea37bf\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
>
> C:\Users\Habib M.
>   Farooq.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\96831bdc0a7a4525ff0542204eea37bf\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
>
> error: failed linking references.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-keep-awake:verifyReleaseResources'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5m 5s 120 actionable tasks: 22 executed, 98 up-to-date

I have trying it from yesterday and searched about it too much on google and `stackoverflow` but still not find any suitable solution for it.

Kindly please guide me and help to solve it and please don't give thumbs down to this question because it is different and I haven't find any answer of it and and I have did everything to solve it.

**Update**

I have added some lines which I found on `github` and the `APK` generates successfully but its not installing in my phone. 
And these lines are following:

```
subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
      afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the supportLibVersion,compileSDKVersion and things of your android project? You can find that on build.gradle.

Comment: Ok I update my answer the build generated but its not installing in my phone.

Comment: It’s not installing because you are getting this error right? You should provide compatible versions to work an app.

Comment: No, I moved from this error and now the build generates successfully but I can't install in my phone.

Comment: What happens? Get any error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used `react-native-keep-awake` package in your application.

The error is that you have not linked the package properly. So try these

```
npm install --save react-native-keep-awake

react-native link react-native-keep-awake
```

And make sure you have removed the previous versions of the `react-native-keep-awake` from your app. To do so check the following files and remove the added lines.

- android/settings.gradle
- android/app/build.gradle
- android/app/src/main/java/[...]/MainApplication.java