# Can I debug react native app(debug version) without having source code?

Tags: debugging, adb, react-native

Recently I have created react-native debug apk.

I have given this apk to my testing team , testing team want to debug this apk, but they don't have source code, so they unable to debug apk.

They just want to see performance and api calls.
Is react native app possible to debug without having source code??

I have created app by following below url.
[Build and Install unsigned apk on device without the development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283959/build-and-install-unsigned-apk-on-device-without-the-development-server)

**Error:**
https://ibb.co/7GZ1MQB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't they start the APK with Android-Studio. There you have some handy tools to profile and you have logcat to see all actions which happends within the app.

No need for the reactNative - SourceCode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @suther, I have follow above answer and tested in android studio but, I'm Unable to see Network call within android studio?? My major concern is I'm unable to see API Calls. Please help I 'm eagerly waiting for your reply...

Comment: Whats about this: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler

Comment: Thanks a lot @suther, Working as per above given link