# Red Screen React Native Reference Error : Can't find variable : _fbBatchedBridge

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native

I followed the steps mentioned in following documents and everything runs perfectly.

[image: react-native start Output]

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
2. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
3. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

Now am trying to run the android app on my device but I get below error.

[image]

[image]

I tried following to resolve the issue:

```
react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

If I  try to run without a server, bundle the jsfile into the apk by running:

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

I get

[image]
I followed all the steps outlined in this question [react native android failed to load JS bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle) but still I am not able to resolve the issue.

I am using my smartphone's data plan on my OSX machine via hotspot. I entered my machine's IP address `inet 192.168.43.14` along with port `8081` in the react-native developer setting.

Any idea what am missing here?

Device details:

```
OSX El Capitan 10.11.1
Nexus 5(Rooted) 6.0.1
Node - v4.2.1
```

Comment: you are not able to connect with development server. Shake your device, you will get dev options and then in dev setting specify your development server ip and port. then reload js , should work

Comment: @Abhishek I have already done that and it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure your are connected to same network. and also check if dev server is running

Comment: @Abhishek : Can you please check my post. I have already added the screenshot of server running & also mentioned that I have configured the IP in "dev setting" & am connected using hotspot.

Comment: Try connecting both your mac and your device to the same wireless network rather than a hotspot. The hotspot could be the issue if you're trying to reach the development server through the network.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have wifi available. So, hotspot is the only way  to connect for few days. Anything else I can try.