# Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run my first React Native project for first time on my device (Android 4.2.2).

And I get:

> unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle

Commands that I used:

1. `cd (project directory)`
2. `react-native start`
3. `react-native run-android`

Comment: Before trying jerry's answer first check have u set ANDROID_HOME in environment variable and in path platform-tool.

Comment: It's a bug in the recent version. You have to use the previous version by using 
react-native init ProjectName --version=0.55.4
The problem should be fixed.

Comment: same error, same context, but the fix is easy: wait for the debug server to change from `Loading dependency graph...` to `Loading dependency graph, done` and hit reload on the app.

Comment: The accepted answer is an extremely inconvenient hack, that complicates the build process and the code base. There are better answers here.

Comment: Use `mkdir ... /assets && react-native bundle --platform..` CAN NOT solve this problem completely，check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511803/10139109

Comment: https://queception.com/question.php?question=10

Answer (score 1030, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue while following the React Native [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#running-your-react-native-application) (developing on Linux and targeting Android).

This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2743) helped me resolve the problem in following steps.

1. (in project directory) `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. `react-native run-android`

You can automate the above steps by placing them in `scripts` part of `package.json` like this:

```
"android-linux": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"
```

Then you can just execute `npm run android-linux` from your command line every time.

Comment: what if we want to modify the file `index.android.js` ? every time in terminal we have to insert command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Comment: Because once it attached to the bundle we can't able to change index.android.js and it will not reflect on app unless you run above command every time before application is running.

Comment: no it is working great you have to insert this commands on the first time you create the project only and then you can modify and run the project anytime without inserting the command again@Maulik

Comment: it will get stuck at `Loading dependency graph...` every time when I rerun it from terminal and it takes too much time. FYI I am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: React native newer versions doesn't contain index.android.js, Hence please use App.js with the command. :) Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem on macOS and your solution worked beautifully

Comment: @ChinthakaDinadasa in my case, it's `index.js`, not `App.js`

Comment: @idleberg what is your React-Native version?, this answer does'n work for me on `RN 0.50.1`, in newest RN version you only have `index.js` instead  `index.android.js`.

For IOS it's working great.

Comment: I followed the steps above and the compilation works, but the images I used in my application were not loaded, they used relative paths, how can I correct the image problems?

Comment: I downvoted because this actually dosen't fix the issue as everytime you maek a slight change you're going to have to rebundle the app and it dosen't allow you to avail of React Native's many features including hot reloading

Comment: Getting this error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Comment: My project doesn't have any asset folder. what could be the reason?

Comment: http://array151.com/blog/react-native-setup-android-environment-windows/

Comment: So anyone has an actual solution to make this work without redoing this command everytime, and using Hot Reload?

Comment: This guy needs a statue! I mean it really worked not only on linux but on windows 10 too

Comment: On Windows what worked for me was adding `F:\AndroidSDK\tools` and `F:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools` to system path, since I used a non-standard SDK folder installation.

Comment: Thanks it is working. can you explain in detail how to automate bundle process in script file?

Comment: Working fine, I am new in react native not able to understand why its happening. please explain, and which is best site to learn it for beginner, Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like a bug in 0.56 related to dependencies. The "solution" is to find the correct combination of dependencies' versions. We found a workaround by installing those versions EXACTLY.The following link helped me to resolve the issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756550/unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo-when-trying-to-create-release-bund

Comment: React native version 0.55.4 is working perfectly with above mentioned steps in answer.

Comment: It saved my life! I updated the gradle on Android Studio. And it only worked again on VS Code after that code! Thanks!

Comment: used **App** instead of **index** for newer versions at two places in the command like this  `"android-linux": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file App.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/App.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"`

Comment: making an entry in the package.json did not help. The CLI method worked for me.

Comment: @IbrokhimjonSaydakhmatov (and everyone that comes later that sees the same error he posted) That error happens when you're not in the project directory.

Comment: Is there a real solution for this yet? I don't want to run this command every time some file changes

Comment: Hot reload menu is not showing in the emulator. Also put --dev true

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18692#issuecomment-439161621 : Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Comment: This is a hack, and it forces you to run this command and regenerate the files every time. The correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows#answer-53326616

Comment: This option is not a fix at all, because if you are in development still don't connected to the metro bundler, this means if you hit "reload" you still getting the error. Also, is using the release version. I'm using the last version from react-native `0.59.8` any updates??

Comment: Thankyou so much, after wasting too much time , i found perfect solution, it worked for me... **I have not created build for ios yet. Do you know if same issue will occur in ios app too, If yes,then How can i resolve in ios?**

Comment: For react-native versions 0.57 and above the bundle output path should be: `android/app/build/generated/assets/react/debug/index.android.js` See [react-native cli documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md#--bundle-output-string) for more details.

Comment: on windows use reverse slash for mkdir
`mkdir android\app\src\main\assets`

Answer (score 180):

If You are running your application on physical device and getting this error

```
unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle
```

try running the command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

It workd for Me...

Comment: Worked for me. For those who dont have the android platform tools on your terminal path in windows, the adb executable is in `C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\`

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer, the other one seems like a hack.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me (Windows, running app on physical device). It's one of the suggested fixes on the red error box.

Comment: It works for me on macOS, but I have to run this every time I replug the device. Is there any way to make this permament?

Answer (score 121):

I spent hours trying to figure this issue out.  My problem was not specific to Windows but is specific to Android.

Accessing the development server worked locally and in the emulator's browser.  The only thing that did not work was accessing the development server in the app.

> Starting with Android 9.0 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/1713216

Comment: Thank you. This was my issue after upgrading `targetSdkVersion` to `28`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It actually fixes the network communication problem.

Comment: This is the solution [used in React Native v0.59.2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/compare/v0.59.1...v0.59.2#diff-38d6a0bccf283e9da50e0e748493777f).

Comment: Thanks for flagging this - was completely preventing my RN app from loading. Disappointing that there wasn't better error messaging around this :/

Comment: It's shocking how all the different answers here seem to solve exactly the same error message. Making debugging even more time consuming and painful. This answer here worked for me! Thanks @neurosnap

Comment: yes, thanks, after added this line, its working fine

Answer (score 71):

Using npm version 4.3.0 react-native-cli version 2.01 react-native version 0.49.5

In the project directory,

- `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- `react-native run-android`

The file name has changed from **index.android.js** to **index.js**

Comment: Kinda sad that FB releases a new version, and instead of fixing this bug - which is clearly hitting tons of people - they break the accepted work-around!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Make sure you have an index.bundle file in your assets folder

Comment: @DarshanPania What does that file do?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky That JS file is an entry point into your app. From RN 0.49 onwards there is only one file `index.js` instead of `index.android.js` or `index.ios.js`

Comment: `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'`

Comment: @Green You can do a quick search for `index.android.bundle` in your project

Comment: After the `react-native bundle` command you wait till it says: Loading graph done. and Ctrl-C that or exit the command window. Then run the react-native run-android.

Comment: for linux : `sudo react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Comment: This is a hack, and it forces you to run this command and regenerate the files every time. The correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows#answer-53326616

Answer (score 48):

I have faced the same problem with a real android device.

Solution: Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41400708/1429832) by Niltoid

1. Find your local IP
2. Open app and shake your Android device
3. Go Dev Setting and>Debug Server...
4. Paste your IP and port; X.X.X.X:8088" (where X's are your local IP)

for Mac user: open your network preference, here you will get your local IP.

Comment: Works for me  (y)

Answer (score 28):

If you are using Windows run the commands in the following way, or if you get an error "Cannot find entry file index.android.js"

1. `mkdir android\app\src\main\assets`
2. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
3. `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 25):

Had the same issue in mac, After spending 2 days i was finally able to get is working.

Since `Emulator cellular data was turned off`, I was getting the `unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle make sure your bundle is running`.

Make sure your `Emulator cellular data is turned on` by doing this package server was able to bundle `index.android.js`. Hope it helps for someone who is in development phase.

Comment: What do you maen `Emulator cellular data is turned on`? Where is that? Virtual device? Real device?

Comment: Emulator means Virtual device that comes from android studio.

Comment: Thank you, for some odd reason, my emulator got corrupted and wifi is gone. saved me.

Answer (score 21):

You can follow the instruction mentioned on the [official page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) to fix this issue. This issue occur on **real device** because the JS bundle is located on your development system and the app inside your real device is not aware of it's location.

Comment: I was getting this problem when running directly from android studio. using `react-native  run-android` fixed it

Comment: Your link does not work anymore, you should reference key helpful parts in future to keep information alive after its source dies.

Comment: So how to run this on a **real device**??

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky i have the same issue and fixed it with official documentation, you can easily check your environment https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html
I can't load porj from android studio (and android folder) but i could do it with root folder of project and terminal.

Comment: By the way the link is expired given in the answer .. Fyi.

Answer (score 21):

I've had this same issue for a number of months now. I initially used @Jerry's solution however, this was a false resolution as it didn't fully fix the problem. Instead, what it did was take every build as a production build meaning that any slight change you made in the app would mean that rebuilding the entire app is necessary.

While this is a temporal solution, it works horribly in the long term as you are no longer able to avail of React Native's amazing development tools such as hot reloading etc.

A proper solution is a shown:

In your `MainApplication.java` file, replace the following:

```
@Override
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
}
```

with

```
@Override
public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    return true;
}
```

as for some reason `BuildConfig.DEBUG` always returned false and resulted in a bundle file in the assets directory.

By manually setting this to true, you're forcing the app to use the packager. This WON't work in production so be sure to change it to false or the default value.

Don't forget also to run

```
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: Holy, this is the actual solution. The accepted answer does not work for hot reloading and is in no way a legitimate fix to the issue.

Comment: This should be the answer! Been whole night trying to fix this with no luck. Thanks, Jesse! Btw, where is the BuildConfig.DEBUG value stored actually?

Comment: Maybe this is the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350932/buildconfig-debug-always-return-false

Answer (score 17):

1 Go to your project directory and check if this folder exists `android/app/src/main/assets`

1. If it exists then delete two files viz `index.android.bundle` and `index.android.bundle.meta`
2. If the folder assets don't exist then create the assets directory there.

2.From your root project directory do

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

3.Finally, navigate back to the root directory and check if there is one single entry file called`index.js`

- If there is only one file i.e. index.js then run following command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- If there are two files i.e index.android.js and index.ios.js then run this `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

  4. Now run `react-native run-android`

Comment: after trying nearly all of these scenarios... this was the only solution that worked for me. Thank you!!!!

Comment: This worked for me after running into this error following the get started guide on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I have removed below line from MainApplication.java. **(Which is previously mistakenly added by me.)**:-

> import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;

After that Clean Project and hit command

> react-native run-android

Comment: Thanks, its also helps me.

Comment: Wow, it saved me!

Answer (score 10):

OS: Windows

Another way to resolve this problem after trying two methods above
(because I installed SDK **not in DEFAULT LOCATION like C:\users\"user_name"\appdata\local\sdk**)

If you noticed that command line announced: "'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

So this is how I get over:
Examples: I installed SDK in D:\Android\sdk
So I will insert path in System Variables 2 more lines:

```
D:\Android\sdk\tools  
D:\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

(If you don't know how to edit path System Variables, here's the topic: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38321/what-do-i-type-in-path-variable-for-adb-server-to-start-from-cmd/38324)

Then I run cmd again: `react-native run-android`

It worked for me.

Comment: even though it is not really connected - this is one of the very common problems and it works as Thien described

Answer (score 9):

I was also facing this problem because when I run projects on the emulator its working fine but on a real device it gives this error. So I resolve this problem by the following solution

**1st step:** First of all open cmd and go to your SDK manager Platform-tools folder

```
cd C:Development\Android\Sdk\Platform-tools
```

**2nd step**: now run this command :

```
adb devices
```

after this command check your device listed in command prompt

**3rd step**: now run this

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Now your setup is done

**4th step**: Go to your project directory and run this command

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 8):

For **IOS:**

**In a terminal:**

```
cd ios
```

**Remove the build folder with:** `rm -r build`

**Run again:** `react-native run-ios`

Alternatively, you could open Finder, navigate to **YOUR_PROJECT/ios** and **delete** the **build** **folder**.

Then run again: `react-native run-ios`

For **ANDROID:**

**In a terminal:**

```
cd android/app
```

**Remove the build folder with:** `rm -r build`

**Run again:** `react-native run-android`

Alternatively, you could open Finder, navigate to **YOUR_PROJECT/android/app** and **delete** the **build** **folder**.

Then run again: `react-native run-android`

Comment: Works for Android! clean and easy!

Comment: Deleting `android/app/bin` folder on Windows worked as well. I had built it the project directly from Android Studio, instead of running `react-native run-android`, and it seems it built something wrong that I had to delete manually.

Answer (score 7):

For this problem I just solve it by running:

```
react-native start
```

then

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

on command line. And then i can run:

```
react-native run-android
```

So i will not waste my time to run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

every time.

Answer (score 5):

I had issue with McAfee on my mac blocking port 8081, had to change it to 8082.

First run your package server:

```
react-native start --port 8082
```

Open another terminal, start the android app as usual:

```
react-native run-android
```

Once it finishes, now rewrite the tcp port that adb tunnels:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8082
```

See the list of adb tcp tunnels:

```
adb reverse --list
```

You should now see a heartwarming message:

```
(reverse) tcp:8081 tcp:8082
```

Go to your app and reload, done!

PS: Don't change anything in the app Dev settings, if you added "localhost:8082", just remove it, leave it blank.

EDIT:
To all the McAfee victims out there, there's easier solution if you have root access, just temporarily kill the McAfee process sitting on port 8081 and no need for port change at all:

```
sudo launchctl remove com.mcafee.agent.macmn
```

Answer (score 5):

> Ubuntu

first time, I created new app with `react-native init project-name`.
I got the same error.
so i do the following steps to resolve this in my case.

1. Firstly run `sudo chown user-name-of-pc /dev/kvm` in my case.
2. While debugging from your Android phone, select `Use USB to Transfer photos (PTP)`.
3. Create Folder `assets` in project-name/android/app/src/main
4. make sure `index.js` be avaiable into your project `root`  directory and then run below command from console after `cd project-name` directory.

> `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

or
for index.android.js then

> `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

5. run command `./studio.sh` in `android-studio/bin` directory. It will opens up Android Studio.
6. run command `react-native run-android`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Make sure metro builder is running to make your physical device and server sync

First, run this command to run metro builder

> npm start

Then you can start the build in react native

> react-native run-android

Their should be no error this time. If you want your code to be live reload on change. Shake your device and then tap Enable Live Reload

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you have added /path/to/sdk/platform-tools to your path variable.

When you run react-native run-android, it runs adb reverse tcp:< device-port > tcp:< local-port > command to forward the request from your device to the server running locally on your computer.
You will see something like this if adb is not found.

```
/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
Starting the app (.../platform-tools/adb shell am start -n 
com.first_app/com.first_app.MainActivity...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.first_app/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: this should be right up to most upvoted answers, as should be one of the first things to check

Answer (score 4):

It may be caused by unlinked assets in your React Native project code base, like when you renames your project application/bundle id or adds an external package without link it properly, for example.

Simply try it in your project root directory:

```
react-native link

react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem also happens if you define an `android:networkSecurityConfig` in your main `AndroidManifest.xml`. The `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your debug `AndroidManifest.xml` will be ignored.

To fix this issue, you have to configure the app to allow http traffic to localhost.

Create a file `android/src/debug/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And reference it in `android/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application 
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" 
        tools:targetApi="28" 
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>
```

Further infos here: https://medium.com/astrocoders/i-upgraded-to-android-p-and-my-react-native-wont-connect-to-my-computer-to-download-index-delta-42580377e1d3

Comment: That's correct. This happens after I have set network config file for some domains. So we also need to set localhost. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

using **npx** before the command did work for me, and the command becomes like following.

```
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

why we use npx, here is the post [Difference between npx and npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm)

Comment: Where to use this command? I tried to use this command but error message shows The resource `/Users/frank61003/Desktop/vanyi-mobile-apps/apps/employee/index.js` was not found.

Answer (score 3):

If when running `react-native run-android` command the second line of the trace is

```
JS server not recognized, continuing with build...
```

it means packager for the app cannot be started and the app will fail to load without some extra steps. Note that the end of the trace still reports success:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The problem is probably some port conflict (in my case it was the default IIS site that I completely forgot about). Another manifestation of the problem would be a failure to open `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui` URL in Chrome.

Once the port conflict is resolved the trace will report

```
Starting JS server...
```

then an additional Node window will open (`node ...cli.js start`) and the app will load/reload successfully.

After that you should be able to open debug console in Chrome with  `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue even when running on a simulator. I did a quick workaround so that I could have the normal dev workflow.

```
private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
  @Override
  public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
    // return true here to load JS from the packager
    // BuildConfig.DEBUG for me was set to false which meant it
    // it was always trying to load the assets from assets folder.
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
  }
};
```

Probably will have to revert the change when trying to do a production build.

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't have **yarn** installed try installing it with chocolatey or something. It should be installed before creating your project (react-native init  command).

No need of creating assets directory.

Reply if it doesn't work.

**Edit:**
In the recent version of react-native they have fixed it. If you want complete freedom from this just uninstall node (For complete uninstallation [Completely remove node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711240/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows/20711410) refer this link) and reinstall node, react-native-cli then create your new project.

Answer (score 3):

don't forget turn on internet in emulator device,
I resovled this error, it work perfect :V
I get this error because i turn off internet to test NetInfo :D

Answer (score 3):

This is a general error message, you may have encountered during the react native application development. So In this tutorial we are going to provide solution to this issue.

Issue Description :
 Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows
Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows

Follow the below steps to solve above issue :

Step-1 : Create "assets" folder inside your project directory 
Now create assets folder inside the project directory that is "MobileApp\android\app\src\main". You can manually create assets folder :

< OR >

you can create folder by using command as well.
Command :
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

Step-2 : Running your React Native application
Lets run the below command to run the react native application in emulator or physical device.

Switch to project directory.
cd MobileApp

Run the below command that helps to bundle you android application project.

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Run the Final step to run react native application in emulator or physical device.
react-native run-android

< OR >

Also you can combine last two command in one, In this case case you have to execute command only once.

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android

< OR >

You can automate the above steps by placing them in scripts part of package.json like this:

"android-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"

If everything is set up correctly, you should see your new app running in your Android emulator shortly.

Answer (score 3):

I have just encounterred exactly the same problem and solved it. So hope to be helpful.

Suppose you are assemblling a **release** application package (.apk)

1. Check if your assets folder exist?: **\android\app\src\main\assets**
   If not, create one.
2. After executing "Assemble Release", check if there is anything in that folder(\android\app\src\main\assets)
   If not, find js bundle file(**index.android.bundle**), which should be in more than one of the following paths:

   *a)\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\release\out\index.android.bundle

   b)\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_assets\release\mergeReleaseAssets\out\index.android.bundle

   c)\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\release\index.android.bundle

   d)\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle*

A better way is to use "Everything" to search the file name: index.android.bundle.

3. **Then copy this file into your assets folder(\android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle)**
4. Go back to powershell or command console, execute:

> react-native run-android --variant=release

It should work.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! Struggled for three days! Btw react native 0.59 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in my situation (`React-native` version 0.61.5 and trying to install debug APK on device) none of the answers helped me, my solution was adding `bundleInDebug: true` to `android/app/build.gradle` like this:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    bundleInDebug: true
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it solved the issue
But now I can't use fast refresh option

Comment: thanks - is this still relevant - 2022? expo doesn't use this project.ext.react and things change....

Answer (score 2):

I have spent half a day figuring this issue...

If you are using the **API target version Above 28.0.0** then you may face this issue.

Just add this line

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in your Manifest Application block.

Manifest Application block code.

```
 <application
        ....
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
.../>
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all check your assets folder exist in this location \android\app\src\main\assets

if no then run this command in terminal

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

then run your project on your android device using

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

when I update react-native to 0.49.5, this problem appears and when I followed this [Breaking changes and deprecations](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.49.0)

it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am facing this issue, lot of search and I resolved that issue.

`c:\ProjectFolder\ProjectName> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

Than Run the react native :

`c:\ProjectFolder\ProjectName>react-native run-android`

Comment: The screenshot is a little irrelevant to the answer.

Comment: In my case , there I have it is problems ,and my react native app don't worked. more precisely I got the same display on the emulator screen for android. I just entered the start point in the package.json in root folder next code   "main":"index.js", and application started. Probably command react-native init have some problem, and not add this code, and when you started, application don't know where to start. I hope so get for all you my little help

Answer (score 1):

For all of you guys who are developing from a create-react-native-app and ejected, and have this issue in `development`,
this is what worked for me
just a little detail from the accepted answer

> (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

here comes the part that changes cos you are in development get rid of the `--dev: false` part:

> react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file
>   index.js --bundle-output
>   android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
>   android/app/src/main/res

after that close all terminals, erase the build folder from android/app/ to make sure you start clean to build your app, open a new terminal, and

> (in project directory) npm run android

will prompt the packager console (in another terminal) and build successfully

Answer (score 1):

Follow this, Worked for me.

https://github.com/react-community/lottie-react-native/issues/269

Go to your project directory and check if this folder exists android/app/src/main/assets
i) If it exists then delete two files viz index.android.bundle and index.android.bundle.meta
ii) If the folder assets doesn't exist then create the assets directory there.

From your root project directory do
cd android && ./gradlew clean

Finally, navigate back to the root directory and check if there is one single entry file called index.js
i) If there is only one file i.e. index.js then run following command
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

ii) If there are two files i.e index.android.js and index.ios.js then run this
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

Now run react-native run-android

Comment: Your comment helped me immensely.  I'm not sure why I needed to delete the two bundle files.  But your directions would perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have entered 'Debug server host & port for device' in Dev Settings, make sure you remove what you have entered.

Comment: Add this as a comment

Comment: After 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be caused by the cellular data of the device / emulator being turned off. Make sure you check that.

Answer (score 0):

for this error :"unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'"

1). check for "assets" folder at : mkdir android\app\src\main\assets

if folder is not available ,create folder with name "assets" manually. and execute the Curl command in terminal.

2). Curl command: curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o"android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"

it will create the "index.android.bundle" file in assets folder automatically and resolved the issue.

3). react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

Chipping in an obvious suggestion that worked for me. Delete the app, restart the server and deploy again from your tooling to device.

Answer (score 0):

If already tried all of above solution but still hit error.
Try to configure your genymotion same with me:

[image]

Comment: please add your configuration as a text; images hosted on third-party sites will be unreachable, at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i was trying to debug my code , (in using Toggle inspector in my android phone and react development ) , I did this simple steps :

1. Open menu in phone ( where Reload is , I can open it by long press on back-button Or Shaking the phone )
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsrOV.png)
2. tap Dev Setting
3. in Debugging -> Debug Server host & port for device should be empty 
   Note : if you wrote port or anything here ( for debugging ) you should clear it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue not with a real device, but with an emulator. I fixed it by running react-native start in the terminal before trying to run the code with android studio. I never encountered this issue when running react-native run-android in the terminal.

Comment: Thx for your answer. What's the difference to the existing answers and the original question (which mentions calling `react-native start` as well)?

Answer (score 0):

i resolve it by this cmd :

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'd forgotten the `Android Emulator` wifi as disabled. 
To solve the issue, I just swiped down the notification bar to expand menu and to enable `Wifi` connection.

After activating `Wifi` connection, the problem has been resolved in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows**

if you sure, node.js is installed successfuly on your system, please check system environment variables and add **C:\windows\system32** in system variables Paths

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing to do before all the other solutions is:

**1. Check whether your device is online or not?**

**2. If you are running the application on the real device then the device should be on the same network where the development server is running.**

More information at [this page.](https://aboutreact.com/unable-to-load-script-from-assets/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @RumitPatel, I did add essential parts, I was just sourcing where I got the answer

Comment: No problem with that. It would be good to additionally explain **how** your solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mkdir ... /assets && react-native bundle --platform..` CAN NOT solve this problem completely,

Notice that, you have to run this command regenerate the files every time when code edited, and it show error again after `Reload` or `Debug JS Remotely`.

The fundamental cause this issue is your app cannot connect with server (because of some unknown reason)

Here is my solution:

- Firstly, start service in other host and port like:

  `react-native start --port 8082 --host 0.0.0.0`
- Then, open app dev menu > Dev Setting > Debug server host for device
- Input `youripv4address:8082`
- dev menu > Reload

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dev Settings -> to Debug server host & port for device -> Input your Computer Wifi IP address (Mac OS : Go to System Preferences -> Wifi to get Wifi IP address)

Final Rebuild application and Run

Answer (score 0):

For me gradle clean fixed it when I was having issue on Android

```
cd android

./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

The most upVoted answer seems working but become hectic for developers to see their minor changes after couple of minutes. I solved this issue by following these steps:
1- Push my code to bitbucket/github repo ( to view the changes later )
2- cut paste android folder to any safe location for recovery
3- delete the android folder from my project
4- run react-native upgrade
5- Now, I see all the changes between the previous and the lastest build (using VsCode)
6- I found the issue in build.gradle file in these lines of code.

```
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 27
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

7- I copied these lines ( generated by react-native upgrade script and delete the android folder again.
8- Then I cut paste android folder back in my project folder which I Cut Pasted in step 2.
9 - Replace build.gradle files lines with the copied ones.
10- Now It works as normal.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

we can fix this issue in **just 1 Second** weather its on MAC or Windows

search **project.ext.react**  this term in your project

and make one changes in that **bundleInDebug: true** add this line. and run your project again.

```
    project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    bundleInDebug: true  // **add this line only**
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using genymotion you will need to start wifi. I looked through all the answers and none worked but by enabling wifi on genymotion emulator this works.

Answer (score -1):

> This solution only for windows OS

```
react-native run-android
```

> run above command from android studio terminal it will resolve all dependence.