# React native BUILD SUCCESSFUL, But App crashes immediately after showing splash screen

Tags: upgrade, react-native

After I upgrade my project from react native v 0.36.0 to 0.47.1 and resolved all the conflicts and upgraded other third party modules too, when trying to run the command `react-native run-android` it got success, but my app is crashing at Launching.

I looked for any repeating third party libraries but no that kind of issue. Also removed the `android/app/build` folder and `android/build` folder but still facing the issue.
I really don't know what is my problem and how can I fix that. Any suggestion?

Command line results seen as follows,

Build Successful for command `react-native run-android`
[image]

React packager ready, but freeze the terminal as follows,
[image]

Comment: in a separate terminal in your project directory run `react-native log-android` before you run it again and see if there's anything that stands out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows the accepted solution here helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ADB reverse ? Did you see the modules being loaded ?

Comment: Yes, I tried adb reverse command too, app icon get generated on the device and app crashes on launch.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried running on android 5.0 and below?
I also faced this issue, that was due to Draw overlay permission.

For android 6.0 and above, Try giving this permission under app settings.

This permission is required mainly in debug builds to display error information on app screen while running react project on device/emulator

Comment: I'm using an android device with android 6.0, I have already gave the permission for Draw overlay for the app. no luck.