# gradlew assembleDebug generates no changes

Tags: react-native, gradlew

### Problem

I have just finished making a few changes in my React Native app and on the android emulator when reloading ( R, R) then changes appear.

I then ran the command:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

to generate a debug apk.

**When I run it on the phone then changes aren't there, it still is an old version.**

---

### I have tried:

1. Deleting the apk in:

   ```
   ./app/build/outputs/apk
   ```
2. Deleting the whole:

   `./app/build` directory
3. Tried the command:

   ```
   ./gradlew cleanBuildCache
   ```
4. Rebooting after cleaning the cache (3) and deleting the `build` directory (2)
5. Tried the command:

   ```
   gradlew clean
   ```

**However I still get an old version of the apk generated each time.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must generate the bundle manually since you run the app on your real device.

[Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)

Comment: It says command not found so i did `./gradlew clean` will check apk

Comment: Yeah, it should do the same

Comment: Still no changes

Comment: I think you must generate the bundle manually since you run the app on your real device right? Try check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows

Comment: worked perfect thanks a lot could you edit your ansxer so I can accept it?

Comment: You're welcome glad it helps you. Ok I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your project directory and check if this folder exists android/app/src/main/assets

If it exists then delete two files viz index.android.bundle and index.android.bundle.meta
If the folder assets don't exist then create the assets directory there.

2. From your root project directory do

   cd android && ./gradlew clean
3. Finally, navigate back to the root directory and check if there is one single entry file calledindex.js

If there is only one file i.e. index.js then run following command react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

If there are two files i.e index.android.js and index.ios.js then run this react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

4. Now run react-native run-android