# Why red screen appears while lunching app first time?

Tags: android, react-native

Why always red screen appears while i am lunching my app first time in react native? there is error "Unable to load script from assets"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows

Comment: Meaning the file is not there and we need  to make the file 'is there'...