# react-native run-android error: Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["E:\\git_app"]?

Tags: react-native

in android enmulator error:
[image]

add i run the code:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`

get this error:
[image]

Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["E:\git_app"]?

why has this error? and how to rsolve? thanks!

env:
    window 10
    android studio 3.0.1
    Cmder

project:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there are files with named App and index in your root project. I assume that you use the new version of react native.

You can't use that command since rn changed the `index.android.js` to `index.js`.

Try using this instead:

- `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- `react-native run-android`

Check the original answer on this link:

[Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows/47035389#47035389)

Comment: yeah, thanks! and this i'm use 'mkdir assets', is ok!