# E/unknown:React: Exception in native call

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, react-native, native

I run android app via emulator, but got some error like below.

Don't know how to fix it.

Is there someone who know the solution?

please help.

thanks.

```
E/unknown:React: Exception in native call
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:198)
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:33)
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:216)
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:994)
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600(ReactInstanceManager.java:109)
                                                                                at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$4.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:746)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Can you please share your JS code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.

I resolve this, by deleting the dependency in `android\settings.gradle` file. That not specified in the `build.gradle` file.

This fix my problem.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Possible Duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows). Try running this command from root directory of your project.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Comment: it returns error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A source of the issue can be `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;` in `MainApplication.java`. Removing that may help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rajat Soni's answer you need to create android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to improve the formatting of your answer: do use punctuation, use CTRL-K to display `code` , maybe some **bold**