# Error enabling remote debugging on freshly ejected create-react-native-app application in android

Tags: react-native

As the title says, after ejecting and fixing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows) issue, the application runs fine, but remote debugging fails with the following error:

[image: remote debugging error]

I've run the typical adb reverse on 8081.

This error occurs after ejecting from a pre-existing app ejected from expo 24/RN 51, and from a fresh testing app ejected from expo 25/RN 52.  Remote debugging worked correctly in the pre-existing app prior to ejection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this, I was able to solve the problem using the following steps:

1. Open up the dev settings menu.
2. Set the debug server host & port for device to localhost:8081

This caused my bundle build to fail, which seems to be the result of the package-lock.json left over from expo.  The resolution for that was as follows:

1. Delete package-lock.json
2. Do the standard react-native clean procedure (rm -rf node_modules, npm install, npm start -- --reset-cache)