# Unable to resolve module 'AccessibilityInfo', when trying to create release bundle

Tags: react-native, bundle

I am running

```
react-native bundle --platform windows --dev false --entry-file index.windows.js --bundle-output windows/app/ReactAssets/index.windows.bundle --assets-dest windows/app/ ReactAssets/
```

command to create release bundle, but I am getting following error

```
Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `C:\Users\godha.pranay\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module does not exist in the module map



This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968

To resolve try the following:

  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.

  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.

  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
```

I tried everything recommended on internet, nothing is working. I am totally stuck on it. Please help.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. After checking some materials, I found that this problem should be a bug of version 0.56.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It seems like a bug in 0.56 related to dependencies. The "solution" is to find the correct combination of dependencies' versions. We found a workaround by installing those versions EXACTLY:

```
react-native >> 0.55.4
babel-core >> latest 
babel-loader >> latest
babel-preset-react-native >> 4.0.0
```

So you have to run those commands in order:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
npm uninstall react-native
npm install --save react-native@0.55.4
react-native run-android
npm install --save babel-core@latest babel-loader@latest
npm uninstall --save babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0
react-native run-android
```

Comment: Do i need to do this every time i create a new project?

Comment: @PravinsinghWaghela Apparently, you need this if you started a project with the version 0.56.
Otherwise, working with previous versions like 0.55.4 does not cause any issues.

Comment: @MujtabaZaidi They corrected the bug in the last version of react native, I highly recommend you to move to the last version.

Comment: I am having react-native 0.63.4, and getting 
error Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `react-native-calendars/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: AccessibilityInfo could not be found within the project.

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Yes, I just updated the react native version of that custom library -- `react-native-calendars`, and that worked for me :)

Comment: @NarendraSingh for me it worked by uninstalling `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`. Then `npm install`

Comment: I got this error before and it was resolved by reinstalling `node_modules`; now it's not working. Also updated  `react-native-calendars` and `@babel/core` to latest versions but still same error.

Answer (score 17):

If you are running the reactive-native version 0.56.0 then downgrade it to 0.55.4.

```
cd "on your project directory"
npm install react-native@0.55.4
```

If you want to know the reason follow [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953).

Comment: thanks for the solution. what is the most stable version of react native? 0.55.4 seems to be stable.

Comment: As of now i am using 0.55.4, but i am not sure if that is the stable version or not

Comment: What if I am running 0.63.4?

Answer (score 8):

i had the same issue.

previous my react-native version was

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0
```

then i uninstall react-native

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
removed 41 packages in 3.999s
```

then i installed react-native

```
npm install react-native@0.55.4
```

again intsalled

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@1.2.0
```

then this installation of creating react-native project work out

```
react-native init --version="0.55.4" myprojectname
```

Comment: Installing react-native before init of the project caused permission issues for me. Specifying the version at init time, alone, did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

```
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.4.1",
        "react-native": "^0.55.4"
      },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
      },
```

then hit following commands

```
    npm update
    npm cache clean --force
    cd android
    gradlew clean
    cd..
    react-native run-android
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 5):

I also found bug in latest of react-native 0.56.0. I tried to downgrade the but still not working for me. This problem in windows operating system not in mac.

Simple I tried:

```
react-native init ProjectName --version=0.55.4
```

It is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

react-native 0.56.0 is broken in Windows platform.
please use 0.55.4

it will fix your problem!

Comment: If the OP is asking for a specific version of react-native, it is generally better to help the OP make their set up work instead of recommending a different version.

Comment: @Nerdi.org then go and do the same comment for all the answers :)  because mostly they said the same

Comment: Your answer popped up in the official SO review queue. We're encouraged to leave helpful comments / votes, or flag if a moderator is needed. I didn't think a moderator was needed, so I replied instead.

Answer (score 2):

The following fixes the issue:

```
npm install babel-preset-react-native
```

A similar issue can arise when trying to run `npm run flow`. The fix for that is

```
npm install babel-preset-flow
```

Comment: Do you need to do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the recent version of react-native. To fix (at least temporarily) the problem use the following version of react and react native.

```
"react": "^16.4.1",
 "react-native": "^0.55.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm cache clean --force` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on npm cache clean --force 
or restart system
or deleting node module and reinstall.
When we create fresh project with latest version it seems top work fine but on upgrading everything seems to stop working

I suggest to start new project.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
npm remove --save react-native
npm i --save react-native@0.55.4
npm remove babel-preset-react-native
npm i --save babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Perfect Solution**

Try to make the version compatible to each other for best way

here is [**the link**](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md)

[image]

and keep everything up to date such as `android sdkVersio` such as `27` or `28`.

Comment: what about babel version, which is also very important.

Comment: You also need to downgrade babel-preset-react-native version from 5.0.2 to 4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

React native + native base + redux + react  -compatible versions till date .
working flawlessly on linux as well as Windows.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ExampleAPP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "eslint": "^5.2.0",
    "native-base": "2.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },

  }
}
```

if you still get error , remove node_modules folder and run commmand in terminal in your project directory

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue fixed - Working 100% !**

```
npm remove --save react-native
npm install --save react-native@0.55.4
npm remove babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

@abinax's answer worked great for me.

I think instead of using latest for the babel packages, version numbers would be more appropriate due to future changes to babel potentially breaking existing compatibility.

Here are the version numbers that worked for me.

```
react-native >> 0.55.4
babel-core >> 6.26.3
babel-loader >> 8.0.4
babel-preset-react-native >> 4.0.0
```

And @abinax's answer with the version changes:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
npm uninstall react-native
npm install --save react-native@0.55.4
react-native run-android
npm install --save babel-core@6.26.3 babel-loader@8.0.4
npm uninstall --save babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0
react-native run-android
```

You may also need to edit your .babelrc file if you're getting this error:

```
Couldn't find preset "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset" relative to directory
```

Before .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

After .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Uninstall your global copy of `react-native-cli` via one of these commands:

```
yarn global remove react-native-cli
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

As far as I understand, your project may accidentally spawn the metro bundler from this globally-installed package rather than your own locally-installed one (I encountered this using the standard `react-native-xcode.sh` build script), and it becomes a problem when there are version mismatches. This is all that was needed to solve my problem for a fork of react-native v0.51 (when clearing caches and reinstalling every local node module had no effect).

I did also remove the following packages, which may *not* be relevant in practice: `create-react-app`, `create-react-native-app`, and `react-native-macos-cli`. Basically, just list all your globally installed packages and uninstall any React Native-related ones.

Answer (score 0):

For me i had to replace the preset "react-native" in .babelrc by "module:react-native"

So .babelrc :

```
     {
     "presets": ["module:react-native"]
     }
```

and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same issue on **Android** in RN `0.72.4` and deleting the `cxx` folder in `Android/App` has worked for me.

I advise you to also delete `node_modules` folder and `build` folder in `Android/App` to ensure it will build correctly.