# React Native: bundling failed - Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo`

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

> error: bundling failed:
>
> Error: Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `D:\MyApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map

Comment: you are importing a module that does not exist look for a import statement with AccessibilityInfo name

Comment: I'm with the same problem here...if you solve, post your answer...

Comment: as I seen, it's a bug in the last version...see this:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953

Comment: here is answer for this issue. It works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51413785/7093519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its some incompatible versioning problems in React native.Try this it will work

1. Change versions of following in package.json
   In dependencies :-

   ```
   "react": "16.3.1"
   "react-native": "0.55.4"
   ```

   In devDependencies :-

   ```
   "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0"
   ```
2. Delete **node_modules** and run **`npm install --save`**
3. Then run application by **`react-native run-android`**

It will run fine ...

Comment: I am using react-native 0.63.4, and error is -- `error Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `react-native-calendars/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: AccessibilityInfo could not be found within the project.`

Still no luck :(

Comment: I'm also facing this in 0.64.2, @NarendraSingh did you find any solution?

Comment: Any solution for 0.63.4??

Answer (score 0):

- Heading

  ### first of all try with

  npm start -- --reset-cache

  If this is not working 
  than delete node modules & npm install
  npm start -- --reset-cache