# react native android error unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from...module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, android-assets

Every time i try to run:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve module `AccessibilityInfo` from `\fcm\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js`: Module `AccessibilityInfo` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

I need to run this command to avoid the error:

```
Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'...
```

I've followed almost every post about this issue without success ([Unable to resolve module 'AccessibilityInfo', when trying to create release bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756550/unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo-when-trying-to-create-release-bund))
What's happening??. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 `react-native init Projectname --version 0.55.4`

That working for me also coz m also facing that issue