# Unable to solve TransformError In React-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have created android app using react-native with expo. After ejecting from expo I am facing **TransformError** issue.
Please someone help on the same.
here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "react": "16.6.3",
   "react-csv": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
},
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-csv-downloader": "^1.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  }
```

Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: have you manually installed dev dependencies ?

Comment: Have you tried the dependency combination in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756550/unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo-when-trying-to-create-release-bund

Comment: @JaydeepGalani Yes I tried with manually