# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AccessibilityInfo' error when using WebView in ReactJS

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a ReactJS (not React-Native) android app in which I need to open a webview (or some sort of popup within the app) for payment gateway. If possible, I want to be able to access the html source of the page opened in this webview and also inject javascript.

To do the above, I'm trying to use the React-Native WebView component  -

```
//Removed all other reactj related code in the below simplified example
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
    render() {return (<div className="App><WebView /></div>);}
}
```

The above code results in a whole bunch of "Module not found" errors when I run "npm start" -

> "ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AccessibilityInfo'"
>
> "ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ActionSheetIOS' "

And many more similar errors. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling various combinations of versions of react-native and babel-presets etc as listed [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756550/unable-to-resolve-module-accessibilityinfo-when-trying-to-create-release-bund), [github](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/issues/124) etc but nothing works.

Also tried to add "babel-preset-react-native" in .babelrc but that resulted in -

> "ERROR in ./src/index.js Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'filename' of undefined at PluginPass.JSXOpeningElement"

My package.json snippet (unrelated stuff removed)-

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4"
  }
```

My questions is - Is it even possible to use a React-Native WebView component in a ReactJS class the way I'm trying to? If not, then what would be the ReactJS equivalent of WebView?

Comment: You can't use `WebView` in React.js. It's a native module. WebView in React Native is a wrapper for UIWebView (for iOS) and a WebView (for Android), both of which are native. Please note UIWebView has been deprecated for iOS.